# Send notification when question is closed or deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete, notifications

By chance I found out that an old question of mine has been deleted. Given that it was very old and highly upvoted, I didn’t lose any reputation and—according to current standards—it was indeed off topic, so that is fine as well. However, I would have liked if I got a notification that someone voted to delete the question in the first place. Similarly to how you are notified when someone edits your posts.

Can we please add a notification to owners when their posts are close-voted or delete-voted?

Comment: Why would this be important? What would you do about it? It is a fundamental principle of UX design that notifications should be limited to *actionable* items. This isn't actionable, and I'd find it annoying.

Comment: Well, while some votes may be arguable, it’s just that I personally care about the questions and answers I post on SO. I often invest a substantial amount of time into them—especially for questions—so I would really like to be informed when something happens to them, regardles of whether I can do something about it or not.

Comment: And we are already notified for comments, answers, upvotes, and downvotes; so it makes sense to be notified about the far more radical thing—close or even delete votes—too…

Comment: @CodyGray You can go put it somewhere more appropriate if you think it has long term value (e.g. it's a general software question and put it on [su]). You can edit it to remove inappropriate parts, if applicable. You can learn from the fact that it was inappropriate for future posts (deleting and/or closing things with no notification doesn't exactly teach anyone anything).

Comment: You are already notified when the question is *closed*, @Dukeling. And like poke said, in some fashion when it is downvoted. By the time a question is deleted, it is really too late to do anything about it anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray You're *not* notified when the question is closed.  And no, it's *not* too late to do anything when the question is deleted.  All of the things that Dukeling listed are things that can be done when a question is deleted.

Comment: If implemented, this should probably be a preference that you can turn off. About 10% of my answers were deleted in a purge of old, off-topic, subjective questions from 2008-2009. It would have been annoying to be notified of each one.

Comment: The notifications in the "recent achievements" dropdown are usually less actionable than closed or deleted questions: upvotes, downvotes, new badges. Notifications for deleted or closed questions would not look out of place there. And that dropdown already combines multiple similar votes for the the same day into a single notification, the same grouping could be extended for deleted questions to avoid a flood of notifications.

Comment: @CodyGray Since when are we not able to do anything about a close/delete? What about editing and putting it in the reopen queue? Or asking why it was closed on a Meta? Or making a new, better question because your old one wont get answered?

Comment: @Dgrin91 - That comment should be an answer. That was exactly the point I was thinking in my head... There's a lot that can be done with deleted posts, and that includes rallying a band of undelete voters to the rescue...

Comment: @jmort253 its not an answer to Poke's question though

Comment: @Dgrin91 - Ah, right... it's not an answer *by itself*, but it sounds like a good argument for notifying question owners when their question is deleted by the community. Giving the owner the knowledge to go out in search of reopen voters definitely supports this feature request. Hope this helps!

Comment: I didn't say that you can't do anything about a close. I said that you *can*. If you're going to be notified, you should be notified about a close. And I think you are---a giant gray box appears underneath the question. Closing is the time when you should edit and fix the question. By the time a question is deleted, you've missed your opportunity. Questions have to be closed before they are deleted. If it was fixable, you should have already fixed it.

Comment: @CodyGray The grey box is not the notification we are talking about. You only see it if you go back to that question. We are talking about something on the top bar. Also, you DID say you cant do anything about it in your very first comment.... "This isn't actionable"

Comment: I second that feature-request after https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391764/1744774.

Comment: Current use case: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391764/did-one-of-my-questions-maybe-older-than-the-deleted-recently-pages-period-ge#comment742711_391764.

Answer (score -7):

I second that feature in accordance with [Tim Berners-Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee):

> ## [Cool URIs don't change](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html)
>
> There are no reasons at all in theory for people to change URIs (or stop maintaining documents), but millions of reasons in practice.
>
> [...] Pretty much the only good reason for a document to disappear from the Web is that the company which owned the domain name went out of business or can no longer afford to keep the server running. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> ### Why should I care?
>
> [...]
>
> When someone follows a link and it breaks, they generally lose confidence in the owner of the server. They also are frustrated - emotionally and practically from accomplishing their goal.
>
> Enough people complain all the time about dangling links that I hope the damage is obvious. I hope it also obvious that the reputation damage is to the maintainer of the server whose document vanished.
>
> [...]

Comment: This has nothing whatsoever to do with the proposal. The links don’t change.

Comment: @CodyGray That's just a partial view on that matter. If I may cite from the excerpt: _"[...] for a document to disappear from the Web [...] to the maintainer of the server whose document vanished."_.

Comment: That makes the assumption that the content has value. Content that is *mistakenly posted* or is *actively harmful* should certainly be deleted, which is what we do here. Furthermore, the URI never changes: it always gets you to the content in its deleted state, so long as you have the reputation privileges to view deleted content. Aside from that, this still has nothing to do with what is being proposed here, which is to show a notification. It also has no relation to closed questions, which also always have the same URI.

Comment: @CodyGray Has value for whom? Views may vary. I agree to those two but that's not the only what you do here. You [delete by age and activity](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba), too. That's what I'm referring to [specifically](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391764/1744774). It's not about the URI. It's about the content. Sry, if I didn't make this clear with my last comment. Great that I can still view it – if I know that it got deleted and if I remember what its URL was (I definitely don't for 1-year-old Qs). The WWW, however, doesn't end at SE's gates. Hyperlinking works worldwide.

Comment: Anyway, I'm fighting windmills here...again. No prob, I have other hobbies, too.

Comment: While the idea is good, this doesn’t apply to deleted content. If content is deleted, then of course it is no longer accessible. If you have 10k+ reputation, you will see that the link will actually stay. – What I was trying to argue about was a way get notified about changes of **your own** content, so that you can for example bookmark or otherwise extract that content before it is gone and non-discoverable forever.

Comment: That's what I meant, too: Being informed of upcoming deletions of one's own content a certain time prior to actual deletion. So that one has the chance and the time to save it somewhere else (or to adapt external references like in my current case) if it's considered that it's worth. Seeable for 10k+ is fine but I don't have that yet and I don't want to think too much about how many of the content created by me got deleted during the last 5 years and I didn't notice.

Comment: @GeroldBroserreinstatesMonica Authors of posts can always see their posts after they've been deleted as long as they keep the URI. Try it: Delete this answer, then refresh the page. You'll see it bordered in red.

Comment: @DavyMwenttofundMonica I know that and it has also mentioned here a few times. May I refer you to my comments above: _" if I know that it got deleted and if I remember what its URL was (I definitely don't for 1-year-old Qs)."_, _" I don't want to think too much about how many of the content created by me got deleted during the last 5 years and I didn't notice."_.

Comment: In that case it's really hard to follow what you're trying to suggest, you say things like "Being informed of upcoming deletions of one's own content a certain time prior to actual deletion. " which makes it seem like you think some sort of grace period to save the link is necessary, when a notification "X was deleted" would suffice. Why confuse that any more than you have to if you understand that deleted posts can be linked to? All this other "Changing URI" and "Time before deletion" stuff that your answer and comments say just make it seem like you don't understand how deletion here works.

Comment: You're right. A grace period would be better. A simple notification (including the URL to the content that's now hidden from, vanished for 99,999...% of the world) would be sufficient since re _"that deleted posts can be linked to"_ – How do you suggest to remember the URI of every Q one wrote in years of SE participation? Keep them in mind, in a text file, in an spreadsheet, in a Browser's Bookmark folder, in a mobile's address app? And check ALL of them regularly whether they still exist for the rest of the word to update existing external references?

Comment: No, I think the original proposal to "Send notification when question is closed or deleted" would be perfect because then you wouldn't have to do anything extra to track your deleted posts. No need for some grace period to save some link somewhere because you can view all your inbox notification. If you ever wanted to know, you just open your profile and look through your notifications. That's why I support the original proposal and find yours very confusing.

Comment: @DavyMwenttofundMonica See the beginning of my answer: _"I second that feature"_. Maybe it's because the Q is a bit inconsistent in itself (though these are related of course): The title says: _"closed or deleted"_. The final question says: _"close-voted or delete-voted"_

Answer (score -37):

**tl;dr:** [this idea is always appealing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-gets-closed) to people who don't answer support questions here on meta or via email, and have [no clue just how many questions get deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221337/around-how-many-questions-get-deleted-in-stack-exchange-and-by-who/221493#221493).

The naive implementation you suggest would generate entirely too much unproductive whining to be practical. You're welcome to suggest a process that would notify only people likely to take constructive action in only those cases where such action is possible - but as it stands, this idea is impractical and hence declined.

Comment: This is the same like not alerting on negative reputation. Why are you so afraid of "hurting our feelings"? Honestly if an alert saying your question is deleted is so hurtful, you have bigger problems in life. Turn it into a preference if you like, but some people do not care about notifications being negative or positive, they just want to be notified.

Comment: And they can keep right on wanting, @Stijn. If they care that much, the information is available in their profiles and of course on the questions themselves, but of course *no one cares that much*. Meanwhile, we're closing and deleting many hundreds of questions *every. single. day* - I have zero interest in dealing with the insane amounts of unproductive whining that would result from rubbing all of these author's faces in this, just to satisfy someone's idle curiosity.

Comment: I'd want to be notified, especially if there are answers on the questions, so I can store them away. When I asked my questions I had a serious reason for them and I come back looking for the same answer again often enough. (If you are concerned about all the complaints, make this a 1000 rep feature and off by default)

Comment: `Telling someone "we just took something away from you, and you can't have it back, and you can't do anything about this" is... uh, not a very nice thing to do.` So its better to not tell them? Thats even worse! Hiding actions and potential options because its going to be more work seems like a bad idea. This just means we need to do  a better job of conveying to users what steps need to be taken to improve to question to reopen status

Comment: @Dgrin91 We don't tell them, because people cannot handle it. We already have enough angry users who never took time to read the help section. If you tell them, they will simply be even angrier.

Comment: So, there's nothing a question owner can do when their question gets closed? Why is it called "on-hold", then?

Comment: Also, what exactly should a user do when their post gets edited? We have notifications for that.

Comment: *“If they care that much, the information is available in their profiles and of course on the questions themselves”* – No, it’s not. The profile only lists deleted *recent* questions. The question that triggered this post was from 2010; it’s not recent enough to be listed there, and simply doesn’t appear anywhere. If I didn’t get a downvote yesterday *just before* it was deleted, I wouldn’t know it was gone and had no way to find it out.

Comment: @kapa [YOU CANT HANDLE THE TRUTH!!111!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMzd40i8TfA). But seriously, hiding info doesn't fix the problem... it just hides it. And if angry people start posting on meta asking why their questions got closed, I dont think its a bad thing. It hardly ever happens now, so I doubt we will get a serious flood of angry meta rants.

Comment: Rejecting a feature request for fear of whining is hardly a reason.

Comment: Current use case: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391764/did-one-of-my-questions-maybe-older-than-the-deleted-recently-pages-period-ge#comment742711_391764 where this feature had saved me one question and three comments (so far) and had saved you, as in _answerers_, 25 times reading, one mod investigation and four comments (all so far).

Comment: heh. @user247702's first comment aged very poorly :P turns out hurt feelings have changed SO inside out, and are the main force driving all changes of late. At least, hurt feelings of a very specific ensemble of humans.