# Pre-flight screening checklist for first/early posts--adaptively pick three items, tune with metrics

Tags: feature-request, new-users

My idea is a kind of "pre-flight checklist", where new users are given some boxes to tick consciously..  It would be designed to help make sure the first interactive way in which people engage moderation is simple--hopefully at least somewhat lighthearted--and clearly automated.

You might object that *"Given so many visible (and invisible) rules, how could you decide which ones to put in the list?  It would be hundreds of items long."*  Well that is pointing to the problem I'm concerned about; rule-creep and bewildered newbies who are scared off easily.  But the concern also points directly to what is usually the best solution to most of life's difficulties... **use magic**.

After all: magic already powers things like the [vote-based advertising for open source ad rotation frequency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251208/211160) *(cough, cough, shamelessplugforRed, readaboutit, cough)*.

If you don't like my questions, ignore their body text.  They are biased to me wanting to speak truth to power--or something--but point is no one person would produce the list of candidates being juggled:

> Congratulations, you're almost done posting!
>
> But we really don't want you to have a bad first experience, getting downvoted and griped at by mean old moderators.  So since you're new, our automated system has used magic to choose three pre-flight questions for you:
>
> [ ] By clicking this box...I swear I am NOT going off to lunch or take a power nap.  I am going to stay more-or-less glued to the keyboard for about an hour, so I can respond to requests people have for clarification.
>
> [ ] I've read over my questyin and am sure it doesn't contian speling erors which may lead to people looking unfavorably upon it.
>
> [ ] I acknowledge that points on StackOverflow are **Fake Internet Points** (tm), and not legally exchangable as currency.  So if I get downvoted I will not take it personally as nothing of value was lost, and instead look over my question again and try to think of how it might be improved.
>
> You can go back to review your post with `[link]`, or by checking the boxes you show you understand.  Then you can post!

So to summarize:

- Crowdsource list items.  Give a kind of template on their length and what markup is usable, limit to one link opened in its own window...etc.  Encourage people to think about the wording and tune it.
- **new item expanding on idea from @Kendra** - to avoid "robo-ticking", in the crowdsourced questions list provide a notation for indicating that there's a twist in the question suggesting it should *not* be checked.  The notation would be an instruction to the checklist generator, and not be displayed.  This would enable the voting and metrics to be able to account for the "reasonability" of the twist, as with any other checklist item attribute.  Off-the-cuff example: *"(dontcheck)I've read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page **all the way through**, and confirm my promise to have read carefully by not checking this box."*
- As with open source advertising, if any pre-flight checklist question breaks a certain score then give it a shot into rotation.  Use executive authority to axe ones that are popular but shouldn't be.
- Shuffle the questions based on percentage of overall points given to all list items.  But metrically analyze if there's any strong correlation between hints that are generating noticeable differences in *"more upvotes, less close votes"*.
- In the open-source ad rotations,  a new top-level post is started fresh after a period of time.  With this, there should probably just be one list...but metrically ineffectual ideas that show no correlation with reduced downvotes/closevotes on questions they screened could be deleted (or have votes reset to 0) after a sufficient trial period.
- Beyond the metric of "how well did the post perform with given pre-flight questions list", track also whether people went back to review their post *(or if the post is still shown on the same page, how long they took between original submission and pressing the second submit)*

Also, I'll mention that somewhere it should be possible to click through to the "master post" of all the preflight questions.  So any asker who *did* find cause-to-pause could see them ordered by votes, and ponder any debate about them being had in comments.  For instance, the draft text above would perhaps link "pre-flight questions" to the master list post.

Comment: Well, your list is kinda bogus, but your idea is sound, so I upvoted. Enjoy your fake internet points. :)

Comment: Moderators aren't "mean", they're "[curmudgeonly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/curmudgeonly?s=t)".

Comment: @slugster Elected moderators and SO employees--well yes they tend to be curmudgeons.  But people with access to moderation tools *(which are indistinguishable to new users who don't know what the diamond mark is about anyway)* are just people with a lot of time on their hands who go through no election or hiring process.  And some of them are, yes, mean.

Comment: While this might help *some* people, I can just imagine a lot of users doing what they do with any other introduction on any other site (including Stack Overflow), "*TOO MUCH READING! CHECK CHECK CHECK SKIP! Now on to my question! :D*". So ultimately useless...probably. I don't know...maybe it provides enough of a speed bump/friction to make some users think twice...but I don't know.

Comment: @Cupcake If it were a fixed list with no data reactivity, I'd say you're likely right... can't pick a set of 3 off the top of my head and argue it would make the difference.  People may not like my three above, but, that's why I say don't make the list the point.  Make the metrics the issue.  If something gets thrown at the wall and sticks, that's reality.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The thing I often want to emphasize is just how intimidating a system with lots of knobs and levers and moderation machinations is. It has turned off smart people I've tried to drag kicking and screaming off of lousy tech and they stay there because the culture and friendliness suits them better.  And often I empathize with their complaints to the reactions here. So being a bit less *"we have teh pointz n u don't, here's the mallet we hit u wit"* offers a chance for people who might shy away to see how ergonomic/adaptive it can be. Friends don't let friends use Google Groups.

Comment: @HostileFork: If they've found a place where experts reside and the culture suits them, more power to them.  Stack Overflow was never meant to be all things to all people, although I would suggest that the number of suitable places where you can go to get timely, on-point, accurate answers like you can here is probably fairly small.

Comment: @RobertHarvey *"I would suggest that the number of suitable places where you can go to get timely, on-point, accurate answers like you can here is probably fairly small."* => ["With great power comes great responsibility" - That's the catch phrase of old Uncle Ben - If you missed it, don't worry, they'll say the line - Again and again and again..."](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fj7c3vBZ7jA)  Which is to say, yes, I agree...but it's a little bit like other monopoly style situations, where the rules *do* change when you corner a market, to have to be more "fair" because of the power you get.

Comment: if you ever implement this, combine it with my old idea: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105838/tips-hints-based-on-tags it basicly adds some rules to the **magic** part, so hints can be attached to various topics.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I was trying to keep it simple, and not mention content analysis.  I'm averse primarily because of how offensive to my senses the "you can't say `you`, but we're not going to mention that using the word `you` in your question title is why we are putting up a big red box".  If the box shows up it should say "don't say 'you' in question titles" and point you to the rule list.  :-/  Which isn't to say that tag-specific or content specific behaviors might not be cool.  My idea is just simpler and could be done in an hour or two.

Comment: @HostileFork: your rules are mandatory, and because of that, content analysis (if at all) should be used judiciously. On the other hand, my rules are suggestions, so no nagging factor there. I just posted my idea because I feel yours is a special case of it, and as a programmer I like to suggest solutions/models that can solve more generic tasks.

Comment: Related?: [Let's have an explicit triage system for questions from new users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236537/163250).

Comment: We could also just show them the text in the middle of a screen for a certain time amount before allowing the confirm the question. It's the same only without the clicking.

Comment: Upvoted for the irony in "*I've read over my questyin and am sure it doesn't contian speling erors*"

Comment: @Trilarion I think the clicking is important in the proposal.  It's kind of like how they make you sign credit card receipts--not because anyone in the process is a handwriting expert.  But if someone has your credit card and buys something with it, that pinpoints the *"well, there's the moment we can identify as you having committed a crime."*  It's the pause and possible delving they might do from the links into thinking twice about learning a little more about the culture before posting.  It might be interesting to let reviewers see what questions the person was shown and checked too...

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky the spelling errors were intentional. [If you were going to fix them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/265671/3), you should have fixed **all** of them `:P`

Comment: I think that this is actually full of win. The list is humorous and to the point. I wouldn't mind seeing it implemented yesterday.

Comment: I think to more encourage the reading of these boxes, there should be some in the list that will actually require you to leave the box unchecked. If someone checks said box, don't post the question and instead alert the user to make sure they've read what they're agreeing to. That way you're actually (somewhat) mitigating the "tick and go" method of most people on the internet.

Comment: @Kendra Interesting idea...in the crowdsource of question text, it could be an attribute on the question encoded somehow.  Added that to the proposal.  One concern might be is that it shouldn't cross the line over into *"literacy test in order to vote, culture bias"* territory.  On the one hand there's robo-clicking, on the other hand there's people who have English-as-a-second-language and might be put off by such a twist, even if they wind up "getting it".  So hopefully all the choices of this nature would be good-natured and fair about it.

Comment: @HostileFork I agree, it shouldn't be anything overly cheaty in terms of reading it. Perhaps a not that would change the meaning to opposite, or lack thereof, would do it and not be too bad. I'm all for this proposal- Even if it's only for the reason of not seeing a meta post every 20 minutes about how mean SO is becoming. =/

Comment: @FooBar One of the issues with this 'irony' is that people who don't speak great English might not realize what those words are supposed to be, which greatly increases the probability that they ignore it.

Comment: I like the idea that some of these should not be checked but they need to be **much** more obvious than the example.  I would have failed that one, what with double negation and focus inevitably being on getting the clicking done as quickly as possible (and also, English is actually my *third* language, but I don't think that's a factor here).  Make them silly obvious, like "This is the one you should not click.  We are trying to make sure you are awake.  But if you're not, dream on."

Comment: Also don't forget the control group, a checklist with no items on it, just like we have now, so we can check how that compares against actual checklists.

Comment: I missed this post when it was new. Determining the most effective checklist items by randomizing and testing qualifying community suggestions is a very fun and potentially fruitful idea. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 35):

I object to the 'glued to the keyboard.' This site should not impose near-real-time. The sequence of 'post a question, get a request for clarification, clarify' could unfold over days, it does not have to be minutes.

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems that advising posters to stick around is a [somewhat popular idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156761) (some related questions in the comments). I agree that SO shouldn't *require* users to stick around, but perhaps for the more high-traffic tags (e.g. Java), I think such advice could be helpful, given the high turnaround rate for those tags.

Comment: Your second sentence is correct; the quickness of the response depends on the type of question and how it's worded, and for more complex questions interactions could spread out for longer periods of time; however, I could imagine that at least for some tags a faster response is the common case. Perhaps someone could run some SEDE queries (can't do so myself, unfortunately, as I don't know SQL) to find out average response/resolution times and maybe some other relevant stats for various tags; that info might be helpful in determining whether a recommendation to stay put would be productive.

Comment: +1 as I side with your objection [(it was critiquing that which motivated this proposal)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265667/).  Yet the list of things would be crowdsourced from the group of moderators who are coming at moderation from often very different ideas.  This just means that if things are bubbling up based on stemming close rates; it may hint people at the complexities...so they're ready for the *"new kind of forum"* that this medium represents.  Being able to click through to the meta post with the votes to see the "how is this list generated" could be interesting too.

Comment: I agree that it should not be required in the general case, and perhaps the wording could be improved and/or softened, but for a first question, it actually makes sense to stick around for at least fifteen minutes to see if there is any immediate feedback.

Answer (score 8):

The preflight checklist is a very good idea. I don't think the questions you provided are good examples, though, and I tend to think that the checklist shouldn't change but should instead be the list of things that any user should check before posting a question:

- Did you try to solve the problem yourself? Have you consulted relevant documentation and your favorite Internet search engine? Did you search for similar questions here on StackOverflow?
- Have you stated your question clearly? Take a moment to read through your question from the point of view of someone who initially has no idea what you're talking about. Will such a user be able to tell what you're asking?
- Is your question formatted properly, including code formatting where appropriate? Did you check the spelling, punctuation, and grammar? (We don't expect perfection, especially if English isn't your native language, but we'd like you to do your best.)
- Have your read through [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) to make sure that your question is on topic and posed in a way that's appropriate for StackOverflow?

Basically, let's put the list of reasons for closing or voting down up there and give the OP the first opportunity to avoid problems. Nobody will be able to say that they weren't warned, then.

Finally, let's put the preflight checklist up for all users, not just new ones. Even old timers can benefit from a moment to check their work.

Comment: I don't know if the checklist appearing should be a pure function of *"first post"*--perhaps more a function of *"when your upvotes thus far vs downvotes has not exceeded N"* -- but displaying it after some certain point would be annoying (I don't want it, unless it's a new SE site). One good reminder for old-timers on new sites is to read the site-specific FAQ to know their rules instead of assuming you know what's allowed or not. And I think if it's not shuffled for metrics it undermines the ability of selecting for what has actual psychological effect in cuing the "think twice" reaction.

Comment: +0 for suggesting this should be applied to old users as well.  I don't agree with that, although otherwise this is mostly +1-worthy.  Maybe the checklist could be randomly thrown up every *n* posts or something, but don't slow down the flow for everyone all the time.

Answer (score 6):

Any prompt with a large amount of text will usually be met with an **ignore & tick** mentality, unless they are forced to read it.... but we can't force them to read it... or can we?

As I typed that I wondered what we could do to make them read it and the best I could come up with is a delay that meant the prompt would have to stay up for a certain period of time before they were allowed to post - simple timer!

Then I thought, they'd just minimise or switch tabs and do something else for a while until the time passed, so a quick search came up with this SO post where the timer would stop if they switched away:

**[Run setTimeout only when tab is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766263/run-settimeout-only-when-tab-is-active)**

Here's a fiddle with said timer: [JsFiddle - Active tab timer](http://jsfiddle.net/LEq4Y/), please bear in mind it's *not my code, not tested, no guarantees about it's usability.*

Probably a terrible idea, just thinking out loud.

Comment: Interesting technical idea, as the goal here is to operate on metrics it could maybe be applied 1 out of every N times to see if it made a difference in close rates (or complaints).  But I do believe the *"tick the boxes and the boxes you ticked can (maybe?) be reviewed by others"* is the extra bit of oomph where people can't claim the rules were buried, and the dynamic selection can help to see which things get ignored and which cause second thoughts.  As I've mentioned before, I wouldn't have as much hope for the approach if three static things were picked by committee; no evolution.

Comment: I like the idea of the metrics. I asked this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260039/57475 relating to pre-post checks, which looks at improving low quality posts and I think metrics could be used on there too.

Comment: A technical idea was suggested that may work better I think, and isn't time-based...throw in an attribute on the question for where its phrasing indicates the box should *not* be ticked.  Let those questions be studied for efficacy.  If they're shown to be important, make sure at least one makes it into each set.  Added to the proposal.

Comment: If it's any consolation, while I think the timer idea is only going to tick people off because of it only working when the tab is active AND still not work because you can just drag it to another screen and do something else while you wait for the timer... At least reading your idea gave me the idea I suggested. So... I give you partial credit as inspiration. =)

Comment: @Kendra why thank you, like I said just thinking out loud

Comment: Something like that timer is a terrible idea. You're forcing a bad user experience on people to try and solve a problem - rather than actually solving the problem. The way to make people engage with the checklist is to make them want to engage with the check list....

Comment: @TimB like I said... was just thinking out loud. Maybe we should do what those crappy links on social media do: _Click this link / Watch this video, you won't believe what happens next_

Comment: No! Just NO! Maybe the user's posting something for the _second_ time, and she put enough effort to read it thoroughly on her first time. Respect her right to skip and continue. If it's her first time, and she has entered poor content, and she does not bother to read it, she will be punished with negative fake internet points(TM) in minutes.