# What is the policy for Stack Overflow and political matters, such as the logo color change?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Just curious, I cannot help but notice the political implications of the timely color change of the Stack Overflow logo and the Supreme Court decision in [**Obergefell v. Hodges**](http://s3.documentcloud.org/documents/2111821/obergefell-v-hodges.pdf). Is there any policy that governs the posting of politically motivated content on Stack Overflow. I have no problem with it, but I would like to know if there is some guideline on what is permissible.

Comment: Also, related (but not a dupe as this concerns the _policy_ while the link concerns just the why of it being changed): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow?cb=1

Comment: The policy is if the SO staffs has a stance on that matter then it is permitted otherwise it is not.

Comment: @William Ouch, that makes me so much more reluctant to post on here.

Comment: @Jonathan: it's also not even close to true, but I don't want that to spoil William's party `:-)`. You should continue to post on Stack Overflow as often as you were a week ago.

Comment: There was a similar controversy when they paid tribute to Steve Jobs on the event of his death. I believe the idea was initially popular with staff and the community, but it set a [difficult precedent as other important tech figures' lives couldn't be/weren't similarly honoured](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109160/), and many felt Jobs was not an appropriate choice. It seems the conclusion was "Hmm, well we don't regret doing it, but let's not do things like this again". I imagine they'll reach a similar conclusion with this: no regrets, but let's not do things like this again.

Comment: @user568458 In my mind that was enough of a precedent *not* to repeat this, but at least not to repeat with such a politically charged issue :S

Comment: @halfer I have a strong suspicion that if the Supreme Court decision were somehow thrown out tomorrow there wouldn't be a celebration in the StackOverflow icon. The truth is this was tied to the founders political views. And it is woefully saddening that it has turned against a minority who may disagree with the decision on any grounds: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298004/2642059 And I hate to see any political agenda overshadow the community of this site :(

Comment: Ah, gotcha - that's where we disagree, then @Jonathan. In my view, overturning old discriminations, and making people equal before the law, isn't as political as setting them up in the first place. Thanks for your thoughts on the matter.

Comment: @halfer I think your comment perfectly makes my point. You agree with the political position of the site owners, and thus feel at liberty to share your position without fear. Others like Ben Voigt who disagree must make a defense of their position. The community is thereby damaged and it's the community, *not the owners* that I'm committed to, so I am disheartened. I will not post my opinion of the ruling here because it is not the right venue. My wish is that the owners of the site had the same commitment to the *entire* community.

Comment: @Jonathan: it sounds like you believe that people opposed to gay marriage are a newly oppressed minority. If so, it is possible that you are not aware of precisely how bold that claim really is.

Comment: (Side note: I can cheerfully inform you that my view about marriage equality would not change, and I would not be in the slightest bit afraid of sharing it, if Stack Exchange took the opposite view).

Comment: @halfer I'm a little scared to open this can of worms, so I won't post it as a question. But now seems like the *right* time to use the rainbow icon to show love for the victims of the Orlando shootings which were primarily homosexual. I can't imagine anyone having a problem with that, but perhaps there is hesitance because the icon was used divisively in the past :(

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Stack Exchange is a private company. So they ultimately have final say in *any* design decisions they make. However, they quite frequently want community input and use that to drive design and feature decisions.

Stack Exchange usually goes mostly off community input, but if they feel an issue is big enough or important enough, either overall or to them as a company, then they have every right to change any part of the site design to acknowledge that.

To that end, I believe the policy boils down to "We'll take community input, but if we really feel the matter should be acknowledged on the site, we as a private company have the right to acknowledge it."

For the example in question, a number of the team are homosexual, Joel included, and therefore this court decision impacts a number of them directly. This gives them ample reason to change the logo to acknowledge this, whether the community likes it or not. Worth note that in this case, the community *did* show agreement in terms of upvotes on a post asking for the logo change and the top two answers in support of the change, the highest voted being from Joel himself.

Comment: You're ignoring the CC BY-SA terms which govern User Contributions to the site.  They can't unilaterally change the design in a manner which violates those terms.

Comment: @BenVoigt Out of curiosity, could you give an example of what they could not do with regards to the terms?

Comment: Actually, what they did today.  It's going to take me some time to type up a full explanation though, and I still have other things to do today, and maybe by the time I get around to it they'll be back into compliance with the license making my objection moot.

Comment: @BenVoigt I look forward to your explanation as _"All materials displayed or performed on the Network, including, but not limited to text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images, illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, and animations (collectively, “Content”) (other than Content posted by Subscriber (“Subscriber Content”)) are the property of Stack Exchange and/or third parties"_ which would include the logo, which is all they changed. So it will be an enlightening explanation I'm sure. Even if they do, as you said, get back into compliance, I would love to read it.

Comment: In short, associating user content with the new rainbow logo is a violation of part 4(d) of [the license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode).  Because I consistently support (across the Internet and in real life) an originalist view of Constitutional interpretation, associating my work with a celebration of a ruling based on dynamic interpretation, paints me as a hypocrite.  That's potentially harmful to my reputation and not appreciated.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, I see. At the same time, had they chosen to change the logo to anything else, i.e. make it purple instead of orange, it would not be a violation, correct? Or in theory, since I'm sure purple is used as a color to represent some movement or such, it would associate you with that movement. Then again, the _orange_ color could be associated with some cause you disagree with and could potentially be harmful to your reputation.

Comment: For example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_Order

Comment: @Kendra: The bits and pixels associated with the image are not the problem -- Stack Exchange clearly intends a message in support of the recent Supreme Court ruling which, as I said, is contrary to originalism.  And this connection is not difficult for anyone to discover -- it's all over meta and being featured in the hot list.

Comment: I in no way mean your point is, well, pointless, I'm just throwing out there that _technically_ you could follow that train of thought for any minor change to the color of the logo. There has to be a line drawn somewhere, and this is a change for just the weekend. (I also still look forward to a full explanation if you find the time to type it up and link it somewhere. I'm a sucker for learning!)

Comment: But I have other places to be today.  So I apologize that future discussion must be delayed.

Comment: @BenVoigt Take it to court if you have such a problem with it. It's not going to hurt your reputation. If you were so concerned about it, you'd cease using any other major mainstream website on the internet, too.

Comment: @BenVoigt - It says, "You must not distort, mutilate, modify or take other derogatory action in relation to the Work which would be prejudicial to the **Original Author's** honor or reputation." You are not the "Original Author" of the Stack Overflow logo.

Comment: @BSMP: clearly true... so try thinking about the content which I am author of

Comment: @Qix: With all due respect, your comment shows that either you don't have a clue about the role of reputation in political discussions, or... well I choose not to attribute to malice that which can be attributed to ignorance.  Suffice it to say that in most discussions of SCOTUS rulings, regardless of which viewpoint you have, if you oppose rule by fiat, someone will look for proof that you favor judicial activism when it obtains your desired outcome.  Well, I don't favor judicial activism, by either the right wing or the left wing, and I don't appreciate it being associated with my profile.

Comment: One thing I think all except the biggest extremists can agree on is that forcing it on user profile pages is going too far.  Particular in the location it is in, right next to the user picture and name.

Comment: I disagree with this interpretation. You may have created the answer, but your content ends there (or at your question, bio, etc).

Comment: @BenVoigt So which of: "distort, mutilate, modify or take other derogatory action" are they doing to your user contributions?

Comment: @BenVoigt your content from SO appears in lots of other places. Some don't respect the license (contact SE). Some do. Amongst those that do, if you have not ensured that none breach your interpretation, and taken action against those equivalent to any action here, then a possible interpretation of your potential allegation is that it is selective. Of course, this doesn't stop you writing about it, but may be interpreted as your concern being other than you state. Yes, if not making a legal case of it, you can freely argue that SE is so much more important, so that's why only here.

Comment: @BenVoigt "right next to the user picture and name". On my profile there's a whole bunch of white space between the logo and my (non-)picture and name. Also note that it is your choice on the profile whether to put your real name, and your own picture. If that is one of your concerns, you could chose to disassociate yourself (for 30 days) from the SO image on your profile.

Comment: @BenAaronson Showing something and putting around denigratory content **can be** a derogatory action. Whether this is the case would require some ruling.

Comment: Ok, while I believe that 4(d) is also being violated, as I already said, I've realized that the clearest breach of license actually comes from 4(c): "If You Distribute, or Publicly Perform the Work or any Adaptations or Collections, ... You may not implicitly or explicitly assert or imply any connection with, sponsorship or endorsement by the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties, as appropriate, of You or Your use of the Work, without the separate, express prior written permission of the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties."

Comment: @BillWoodger: If you know a way to stop my content from being displayed in association with the words "Marry anyone you want", even if that means temporary complete removal from the site, then please do explain.  But note that while putting that next to my name is the worst, I find all combinations of that logo, that text, and my work to be objectionable.  Under the license all adaptations and collections need to clearly delineate what portion represents my content and viewpoint, and what has been added ex post facto.  That's all I want.

Comment: @Ben Voigt You seem to be looking for spurious interpretations of CC-BY-SA because you don't like an opinion expressed by the owners of SO (a private company). I'd point out you are free to express dissent on your profile. You could post the business about "supporting an originalist interpretation of the Constitution" if you like. But remember, the users of SO are international, not just in the USA. You can make your point but it might be lost on many SO users. IOW, you have the right to express your opinion, but  many may not really care.

Comment: @Kendra: Over here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298004/103167

Comment: @Kendra hover over the title and see, `"Marry whomever you love.  Even if they're not a developer."`  It's more than just pixels being displayed.

Comment: Not really the place for it, since you asked.

Comment: @BenVoigt If you think your content is associated with the SO logo, then would it imply that the Author of the logo is associated with every and each profile of this site?

Comment: @BenVoigt One can post ads on CC-BY-SA material as long as you follow the rules. And there's ads for *everything*, and condoned clone sites with them. So you have a very big fight to go after if you want to stop juxtapositions of graphics you don't like with some programming content you gave to the Internet under terms with precedent for their meaning...especially using a legal argument that is patent nonsense.  You are free to raise objections and "pull your sponsorship" from SO over a little rainbow icon too close to your name.  It's a free country, and now even a little bit more free.

Comment: Folks, if you want to discuss Ben's idea on how the license is to be interpreted, you should really go and put your opinions on the meta question he linked to, where it will be relevant to the post at hand. This way, the discussion on it is _all in one place._

Comment: @FelipeAls: It seems likely that Stack Exchange arranged for a separate license for use of the various logos, that does not require attribution everywhere it is used. In any case they are using the site logo without attribution, which supports a conclusion that although the site logo is associated with the various pages where it appears, including profile pages, some of which contain users' political speech, the author of the logo is not being associated with the profile pages or that political speech. If the logo contained a signature of the artist, there might be an inappropriate connection

Comment: 4(d) does not give you veto over what else appears on the same page as your content, unless it goes and says "this content supports this message".  You'd have an uphill battle if you argue that "being on the same page" as a rainbow SO logo is sufficient.  You'd also have to make the argument in a jurisdiction where that clause applies.

Comment: Any script to restore the rainbow one? :)

Comment: Any script to restore the old logo for anyone who views your posts?

Comment: So... not to add fuel to the flame, but to bring things back to the legal side of things (which is the part of this discussion I find interesting) I think the key clause is actually "You or Your use of the Work". Looking at the definition of "You" in the license (yes it's defined). SO is technically allowed to shift their cultural identity (which is effectively what this boils down to) so long as they hadn't violated the agreement up until that point.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: That's impossible. Scripts are client-side only.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus The legal discussion does not belong on this answer, but on Ben's linked Meta discussion, over [here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298004/103167)

Comment: @Cerbrus, I was hoping someone would say "but what if the viewer doesn't agree with your stance on the issue?". :P

Comment: The huge problem I see is that the site owners do not stick to their own hallowed etiquette. There are rules over and over for users not to post irrelevant questions ('closed as opinion based', 'off-topic' etc. etc.), but if some SO-VIP feels he should fumble around with the main menu because he is gay, that is tolerated, even supported. Do moderators fear for their paychecks? This is making the site look as ridiculous as could be.

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald Why would anyone worry about their paychecks with this change when the CEO was completely for it?

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald: heh, the **volunteer** moderators must be really worried about that. "Oi you, if you don't fall into line, I'll withhold the zero coins I was planning to pay you" etc. Blackmail at its finest `:-)`.

Answer (score 48):

The [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) tell us not to do that anything:

> ... likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race,
>   gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At
>   all.

The current / recent change is a good example. Whatever your opinion, gay marriage is a divisive issue - and the change to the rainbow SO logo is clearly alienating some users.

For that reason, **I feel that SO/SE sites should stay away from political issues**.

Comment: If it's alienating people in much the same way that desegregation alienated racists... that may not be a bad thing.

Comment: @canon: ...according to _your_ personal beliefs. That's the problem here. They're _your_ beliefs. They happen to be mine too, but, so what?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the only way to not offend anyone is to not say anything. I don't see what people hope to gain as individuals from making a fuss over a temporary change in color to a logo.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: Writing off people who disagree with you as "making a fuss" about something perceptibly insignificant just because it aligns with _your_ views is pretty cowardly. This whole debacle has been offensive because of its US-centric nature. My user profile looks like I frankly give a flying frak what happens in the United States. That's not cool and, as Ben said, may violate the CC agreement.

Comment: @canon, so it's okay to offend and alienate anyone with whom SO's owners disagree? Do you think the message not to offend or alienate people retains _any validity whatsoever_, or has it become a politician-tier empty promise?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I really don't think SO's owners were intending to offend anyone. People just get offended over things that don't concern them in any valid way. It happens all the time, but that's why most of us become more mature as we age instead. This whole debate is literally just people saying "I don't want people to do things that I don't think they should want to be able to do, and I'm annoyed by that they now have the right to do what I don't think they should want to do". Weird. Honestly, I'm neutral about it, and considering I'm not in any of the LBGT, not sure why I should be concerned

Comment: The intent wasn't offense, but they knew that offense would happen and they didn't care. The whole debate is that some people are surprised and concerned that a programming Q&A site with such an emphasis on code and neutrality is now endorsing political positions with no other justification than "I really want to, and I do what I want."

Comment: @canon, and the same way as recognising Palestine as an independent state alienates 'apartheid' Israelis?

Comment: @Benjol: bagsy you don't get put on the peace accord committee! `;-)`

Comment: I'm not against the logo change, but given the ruling laid out in the help pages, I feel that the logo change is a classic case of 'do as I say, not as I do'.

Comment: @Benjol, Stack Exchange is not a site about Israeli / Palestinian relations and it is not a site about LGBT rights. The logo change was inappropriate for this site as would be the flying of either a Palestinian or Israeli flag.

Comment: BUT, The site is privately owned. They can do whatever they like. We each have a decision to make. That is: Is the changing of the logo enough of a breach of etiquette (breach of TOS) to make me stop using the site? I didn't like it. It offends my Christian sensibilities. Will I stop using SE? Probably not. SO has sites dedicated to Christianity, Judaism, Islam and I don't know what else, so there's obviously room for everyone and every opinion.

Comment: @TecBrat. Yes, but if you look at the majority of the people defending this decision across the multiple questions asked here, they all start trying to defend it from an ethical/logical point of view. Then eventually most fall back on what you just said. Which is symptomatic of [something](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298086).

Comment: Hi TecBrat, yes, the site is privately owned, but that is NOT a complimentary ticket to violate your own etiquette and rules

Comment: Well then you might want to post on the main meta asking them to shut down [politics.se]

Answer (score 12):

I suppose this question seeks an official answer from Stack Overflow, and it's worth considering that the readership may not get one - we are not owed anything in this regard. We should remember that on Stack Overflow we're lucky to get any input at all into the site, and – as far as I know – the rainbows that adorned Twitter, Soundcloud, Lyft, Google etc. were not put to any sort of democratic committee.

Whilst I think the Meta communities are great, I am not of the view that Stack Exchange is different to the other big US tech firms, as has been suggested in recent days. Stack Overflow is just a company that gives a bigger window, and a bit more community steering, into its operations. I think it is good that it does.

Several wild claims have been made recently about "the slippery slope of political activism", which I think needs to be marked out firmly as unhelpful hyperbole. I don't know whether one speaker was serious that Nazi flags would be next - did Godwin's Law need further testing? Taking sides on Israel/Palestine got a mention, as did endorsement of ISIS flags, a symbol for each of the major religions, and Hillary for POTUS too. Oh dear, oh dear. Do these speakers really believe this stuff will go into the logo next?

There have been three issues I am aware of that have ruffled the feathers of one or more Meta posters:

1. A note on the passing of Apple founder Steve Jobs
2. A pilot program to help mentor new female programmers in the US
3. A celebration of marriage equality in the US

From this list I think we can roughly circumscribe the sorts of logo changes and minor top-bar celebrations we can expect in the future. I am guessing here of course, but perhaps a list of this kind can help reduce the wild claims that Stack Overflow is soon to endorse Mr Unicorn Waffle-Toaster for President:

- The passing or anniversary of notable computing visionaries and leaders (item 1)
- New civic rights that impact on Stack Exchange as an employer (items 2 and 3)

Since Stack Exchange is an international and remote-friendly employer, it could have celebrated the marriage equality referendum in Ireland too, as Reddit did. However, I don't think the lack of a logo change is a problem here - we don't want to get into the opposite problem where an SE site is *obligated* to celebrate one thing or another! Perhaps there will always be some case-by-case examination.

With this in mind, the set of things that might be endorsed in the future are not likely to include endorsements of pony fascism: it is stuff that, whether every reader likes it or not, is related to Stack Exchange's mission. Have I missed any categories out?

Comment: Er, upvote and agreement.  Sorry for misunderstanding, that I don't understand.

Comment: "We should remember that on Stack Overflow we're lucky to get any input at all into the site".  I agree.  Sometimes people lose sight of the benefits of this community.

Comment: [The speaker who used the example of whether it could be Nazi swastikas was a Stack Exchange employee](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298004/remember-when-you-promised-not-to-imply-that-i-support-your-political-message#comment213083_298014)  (Admittedly, I did say that the reason that a "opinion of Stack Exchange, Inc. and not individual users" disclaimer is an absolutely requirement was that the same license clause protects us against unsavory messages)

Comment: As you mention in your answer, fascist endorsements are highly unlikely - but there are so many other sensitive topics. A very good example would be something like abortion - the right to life of a foetus against the mother's right to choose etc. _[please no one start discussing it now]_ It's examples like these where no side is (trying to be) intolerant or bigoted etc. but most people feel very strongly one way or another about the argument.

Comment: There's all this discussion about a logo change for a widely supported (self-included) topic. It's not impossible to imagine SE picking a less universal right one day...

Comment: @BenVoigt: the point of my post was to warn about spurious and frankly daft suggestions from people who apparently are seriously suggesting there is a risk of swastikas going into the logo. I can't see any indication in Jaydles' message that SO is considering that next. I think he/she is pointing out that the modification of the top bar does not create an implicit endorsement in the way that you claim.

Comment: @Mikaveli: that you cite abortion as a "great example" illustrates how silly and over-reaching this discussion has become. Yes, it is a contentious topic, and no -- I am sorry this needs saying -- Stack Overflow will not be looking to be celebrate legal rulings on this topic, with a logo change or similar, into the future.

Comment: I've tried to delineate a sensible set of rules as to how SO might pick its topics, and I think I sort of missed one: being a model tech employer. The manner in which SE supports female and gay programmers is above and beyond the minimum legal requirements, and it is just good marketing as well as creating a positive and welcoming work environment. An assistance program for people of colour would fit in just fine, for example, and is precisely the same thing as other good tech employers are doing in the United States. This stuff really isn't radical.

Comment: @halfer How do we know? Marital status, for example, has got nothing to do with an employer... Also, your assistance programs are also highly debatable - _positive discrimination_ is still discrimination.
Personally, I just hire the best person for the job equally!

Comment: @Mikaveli: marital status presumably has an impact on pension rights and death in service life insurance benefits - plenty to do with employment. Additionally, the celebration of marriage equality across tech firms was another way for good employers to say "you are welcome here".

Comment: As for positive discrimination, well you are welcome to your opinions on that, as is Stack Exchange. I'm not in the US, but I expect a basic level of anti-discrimination will be written into law, so there's not much you can do about it. If you are in the United States yourself, lobby your elected representative?

Comment: @halfer and dependants don't? My point is it has no relevance on someone's ability to do the work and their employability.

Comment: @Mikaveli: your discussion is veering rather off-topic, sorry. If you want to respond to the thrust of the post - how SE might choose its celebrations and assistance programs - that's fine.

Comment: @halfer Now you're contradicting yourself. Yes, in my country anti-discrimination is written into (employment) law. Assisting someone based on their (perceived) race or skin colour would likely fall foul of that...

Comment: BTW you mention "wild claims about the slippery slope", but your answer then goes on to prove evidence that political activism in Stack Overflow banners concerns ever more contentious topics.

Comment: @BenVoigt: the dividing line my post tries to show is that topics "related to SE mission" are relevant, and topics "not related to SE mission" are not relevant (and would not be likely to be reflected in logo changes soon). The three small events I refer to are not contentious in relation to the SE mission (since they are related to tech, or being a good tech employer).

Answer (score -7):

Using the phrase **political issues** is nebulous.  Is any issue that is discussed by any government at any time suddenly a "political issue"?  If so then programming itself is a "political issue"...lots of questions here could be used theoretically *(if not explicitly framed as such--which is also tolerated)* to crack passwords or DRM or whatever.

If the question might be targeted more formally it would be about *"non-software-engineering-related-issues"*.  In particular... ones that metrically might be unusually divisive--and hence "distracting".  The argument is thus perhaps framed about **distracting issues**.

Many are certainly tired of me beating a dead horse *(and probably tired of me in general)*.  But I've already pointed out there are already "distractions", like the hats and the Tamagochi/StackEgg.  And I personally *do* like that sort of thing... *but* I just feel a lot of feature requests [haven't even been tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265671/pre-flight-screening-checklist-for-first-early-posts-adaptively-pick-three-item).  In my mind they'd be easier to write and maybe solve some of the problem dynamics.  <sub>(cough) except it's always easier said than done, and implementation is only part of it...you have design metric studies too to see how it worked and tweak it, but stackoverflow isn't open source so I can't submit a PR to offer how they might be done, etc.(cough)</sub>

So here we are left with a needed definition of what the "clear and present mission" is, and what **distracts** from it... plus how much "distraction" is implicitly tolerated because it is fun and doesn't make enough users angry.

If I had to distill the inciting issue to "distraction" with a rainbow icon and who's most responsible, I'd say it's the people having a fit about it.  They *claim* to be programmers and *claim* to care about solid code, but they somehow aren't at all worried about who put the bug in their own brain to where they're digging up creative commons licenses and having an aneurysm to figure out why a slightly more colorful StackOverflow icon too close to their name or picture is wrong.  Even if your sexual identity and what you approve or disapprove of is sacrosanct, if what people think *you* believe can be derailed by a juxtaposition like that...I'd be more worried about that vulnerability much more.

Still I mentioned I have been in opposition to distracting issues, or ones with clear bias.  I have spoken out against that meta post for the "girls only can write this email address" mentorship idea promoted on Meta by SE.  But that's different...I think it represents the *opposite* of why Joel thought it was ok to have a little icon to support the neutral position becoming law.  And a one-off icon that took a few minutes can't irritate me in the "distraction" sense on its own merit, vs. the hats or the eggs in a sense...because it took a few seconds to draw.

If anyone calls themselves a technologist, you've gotta be ready for AI rights.  So you think it's weird when something has nearly identical DNA and feelings, yet has the same genitalia as you but wants to live in your world and be accepted?  ["Oh please.  Tell me more."](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/condescending-wonka-creepy-wonka)

*(For me personally, I won't be truly vindicated until un-marryable single heterosexuals can [tax-deduct their cats](http://metaeducation.com/media/shared/cat/pathological-cat.jpg).)*

Comment: (I agree that some things on SE sites can be distracting. For example lots of bold, super, italic styles in the same post! If you emphasise everything, nothing gets emphasised).

Comment: As to your topic, it kind of sounds a bit hostile and dismissive to me, a feeling rather confirmed by your calling downvoters "cowards". The discussion about anonymous downvoting has rather been done to death, and the outcome of that was that it's perfectly OK. I vote that everyone - on both sides - has a rational and civil argument, and that where appropriate we agree to disagree.

Comment: @halfer Thanks for putting your downvote in my recordbooks.  The rest are on SE's.  Nite.

Comment: Hmm, odd. I thought I _had_ downvoted here, and replied in that vein, but it appears that I have not. I don't know what you mean by "the rest are on SEs". You are most welcome to respond to the topic of my comments, and I earnestly would like to understand your position. As it stands you are opposing the logo change so loudly, I cannot see that a "no politics" personal rule could possibly be the cause of the volume.

Comment: @halfer Opposing the logo change?  Uhhhh, er, what?  Perhaps you misread.

Comment: Heh, is it my misreading, or your post? `;-)` OK, I've re-read it again and now concede I am not sure what you are saying (though I suspect it would be clearer if compressed into half the length). My points about tone do stand though. Perhaps it is just a complex joke, with your fork being hostile 'n all!

Comment: Life itself might be a complex joke, but I think the post isn't that opaque. I challenge the question of what it means to be "political" and if we really have a clear definition => turn it to say the question is about "distraction" => if "distraction" is the metric then I've picked some beefs about that in the past, but => the people turning a simple logo change representing a civil rights advancement into a firestorm seem more like the "distraction" to me.  I ask for [more future, please](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZngYDDDfW4); because I hold software engineers to a higher standard.

Comment: I don't know what this post is trying to say either.

Comment: @Cypher TL;IL (too long, illiterate): A: "Political issues" isn't a well-defined term, so that must be defined well before talking about it B: People are looking for any excuse to talk about why "a temporary logo change isn't what the site is for", but then you need to define precisely what the site is for & there are more relevant challenges than grotesque raging homophobes having a conniption fit. C: The legal answer "it is what it is" e.g. it's StackOverflow.com registered to people operating under laws and you can't do much if they don't break them except protest and that's your right.

Answer (score -9):

I would like to have an election where the user community is allowed to vote on whether stack exchange should be used to promote/support political or social causes in the future.

There seems to be a hardcore group of Stack Exchange users which slam anyone who goes against the CEO and the other co-owners of this site. They stifle anyone who goes against their view of Stack Exchange by locking their posts, and even deleting them before a full debate can flourish. What is the CEO afraid of? just give us an election so we can see what the community feels/thinks about this issue. that is fair and square and democratic.

Remember we, the users, made this site a success.

---

The popularity and usefulness of the Stack Exchange sites has arguably been mostly as a result of the hard work and effort by the software engineers who have posted questions and answers. Without them Stack Exhange would have been a flop. Therefore I argue that the CEO of stack exchange and the board should not have unilateral sway on whether they should be able to promote social and political causes. The site is just as much the engineers who have contributed than the CEO and his board. There needs to be a referendum on whether stack exchange should be used to promote social and political causes.

I only realised there was voting on whether this should go ahead or not after the event. For people who are saying that this was done democratically give me a break. Elections are announced to everyone in good time so that people can prepare to make their vote.

Comment: _"Therefore I argue that the CEO of stack exchange and the board should not have unilateral sway on whether they should be able to promote social and political causes"_ As I pointed out on your earlier question, as a private company, Stack Exchange has _every right_ to completely disregard you and the outcome of any community-initiated vote. They are completely within their rights, as a company, to have ignored the original request's outcome had it have gone far in the negative instead. It was not an election, but a feature request that they were already planning to do. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) For this reason, they featured the post rather than make their own to announce why they made the change. They did not feature it to try to get the community's feel for things, they did so only to pin the explanation for the course of the logo change. In the end, no matter what you do or say, the CEO of Stack Exchange and the team that run the sites _will always_ have unilateral sway, as they are the ones who pay time and money to run these sites. Until you start paying for all of that, you don't really get a whole lot of say in the end, aside from what they give you on certain matters.

Comment: Thinking about it, there may be _one_ sole exception to where Stack Exchange would not have unilateral sway on things: That would be when what they wish to change would break a law. But this did not do that.

Comment: @Kendra and as I have said before this privately owned company would be nothing without the community effort over the years. It's the community which makes this site what it is. Therefore they should have more say in these matters.

Comment: It doesn't matter if they would be nothing without us. If they make a change the user base disagrees with entirely, then they are the ones who risk their business going down if all the users decide to leave. It's a case of they _should_ listen to their users, but they are _in absolutely zero ways_ required to. Good business sense does not a hard fast rule make.

Comment: It's also worth noting that they take our input on _a lot_ of things. We as the community set the scope for the sites. We can request and vote on features, which can help get those features accepted or at the very least checked for feasibility. That they take our opinions for so much is a great thing- But they are still not required to do so.

Comment: This is not some technical feature request to make the site better. This is a a feature request which had political and social implications. The fact that they did that when part of the community disagreed with it stinks.

Comment: It still _doesn't matter._ It doesn't matter what the feature request is, it doesn't matter what their reasons behind it were, they still have _complete_ right to change whatever they wish on the site with zero prior approval from the users of the site. Nothing you argue here will change that fact. Yes, to those who disagreed with the decision, it stinks. To those who agreed, it's great. But that does not matter in terms of the policy of the team being able to make such changes.

Comment: Do note that I fully understand what you're getting at, and where you're coming from. I completely respect it as well. The problem is, that's "ideal" thinking- In the real world, it just doesn't work. The private company will always have the final say, and it just becomes a question of if their say lines up with what their users or customers say.

Comment: And that's my point. The users should matter and there should be a referendum on this. What does SO have to loose over doing that? I'm sure it will repair the damage done already

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov If Stack Exchange was based in your country, that would be a 100% valid argument. Since the issue currently is why Stack Exchange can do this, however, US laws and rules are the only ones that matter in the situation. As a US based company, Stack Exchange is completely in their rights to do what they did. I'm sorry you don't want this to be US-centric, but in this regards it must be.

Comment: @Oleg: the problem with sweary comments is they auto-delete when someone (cough) reports them as offensive. Please repost, minus the hostility.

Comment: *"Without them Stack Exhange [sic] would have been a flop. Therefore I argue that the CEO of stack exchange and the board should not have unilateral sway"*.  Hm.  I think this calls for a remake of ["Don't You Want Me"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPudE8nDog0) by Human League.  "You were workin' in a bakery then at Microsoft...when I met you..."  I agree *in a sense*, but this is just different.

Comment: @HostileFork, why is it different?

Comment: Take a moment to reflect on your post. Read it out loud. Check the emphasis. Maybe read it out loud again and replace "Stack Exchange" by "Facebook" or "Twitter" or any similar company. Maybe you'll come to agree with my comment.

Comment: @I4mpi, I don't contribute to those other sites. I do to Stackexchange. I don't want my work to be associated with any social or political causes whether I am for them or against them. This should be a site dedicated to technical matters related software engineering only.

Comment: @I.K. _This should be a site dedicated to technical matters related software engineering only._ - Which it already is. SE decides to change the logo for the first time in seven years in celebration of an event (== not to promote a cause; it was a done deal already) and now everybody loses their minds and thinks they have to speak up or otherwise SE is going to start to decorate everything in nazi flags or otherwise become political tomorrow. Pro tip: they won't (it would lose them a metric crapton of users), and all this agitation is just making you and everybody else look stupid.

Comment: @I.K.: I think this is heavily downvoted as it was hostile to start off with, even before you added the shouty caps. I doubt this is the best way to persuade people to your cause. You can still improve it though: remove the all-caps and the bold, and soften the language a bit. Bonus points if you can work out a way to keep everyone happy, rather than just the group opposed to the logo change.

Comment: @l4mpi, celebration is a form of promotion. Since this site is made up of international users, for some LGBT issues are just as offensive as Nazi issues. Don't think that everyone has the same mentality as yours.

Comment: @halfer, the bold is just to get noticed as my post is way down the pecking order ;). Also I've had hostile behaviour from the "for the logo" camp.

Comment: Ah, alright, removing restrictions on a state-sanctioned form of personal union is potentially just as offensive as gassing people based on their race or the shape of their nose, gotcha. Sadly you've completely missed the point that _this happend for the first time in the seven years of SEs existence and you can bet it won't happen again anytime soon_. But feel free to be agitated some more, I bet if you just capslock hard enough then SE is going to listen to you.

Comment: @l4mpi, again it's your bias. Don't you agree that LGBT issues are offensive in some cultures and countries?

Comment: Everything is offensive to somebody. If we remove everything that's offensive, the PHP and Java tags would be pretty empty. In my case, I'm rather offended that you're still missing my point.

Comment: @l4mpi, and I say you're missing my point, but I'm not offended :).

Comment: Ah, this isn't just opposed to the logo change, is it? It's quite openly homophobic. The purpose of the logo change in the first place is to assert that gay people have a right to an equal place in society, and that these rights remain even if some people do not like it. The Nazi comparison really does your stance no favours at all - and I dread to think what countries you might be appealing to when you suggest that LGBT rights are "offensive somewhere". Saudi Arabia?

Comment: @halfer,  As I have said in comments earlier, my stance is that no causes should be promoted whatsoever whether a person is for them or against them. So what if a country or culture is against LGBT. They have a right to hold that view just like US now holds that it is for LGBT. You really are a biased person. The Nazi comment was first made by l4mpi, I just continued with it.

Comment: No, _I_ didn't make that reference first, multiple other people did it in the various discussions about the subject as a "slippery slope" argument; e.g. "what if the SE CEO would be a nazi instead of gay" and similar BS. It's also referenced [in this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298252/1110381). And I'm not exactly sure why your comment was addressed to me, I guess you didn't realize that the last comment was written by @halfer and not by me...

Comment: @l4mpi, I corrected that, apologies for the mistake. You made the first reference with my post. That's what I meant.

Comment: @I.K.: well, you'll do very well not to make comparisons with fascism. It does not matter if someone else mentioned it first, you said "for some LGBT issues are just as offensive as Nazi issues". That is hyperbole of the first order, and it does not help your case.

Comment: @halfer, again you are showing your bias. There *maybe* people out there who view LGBT which the same disgust as Nazi issues. You can't say it is hyperbole.

Comment: It is worth bearing in mind that the two sides of the debate are not the same here. Advocates of marriage equality are not looking to prevent traditional marriage, but opponents of equality are specifically interested in preventing same-sex marriage. It is thus of concern that some folks on Meta are using the opposition to the logo change as a cover for their real belief, which is to reduce the civic rights of another subgroup (to their credit, some people are being honest about their religious and political motivations - I disagree with them, but the honesty is appreciated).

Comment: @I.K.: it is not healthy for you to advance someone else's repellent argument - you either agree with it or you do not. My view is that you do, but are unwilling to say it. As I said in my prior comment, which crossed with yours, if you are in favour of reducing someone else's civic rights, you should be willing to say so quite explicitly. Don't just advance regressive environments like Saudi Arabia (or wherever else) as evidence that we must not scare the horses.

Comment: (In general, calling someone "biased" does help any discussion. Everyone is biased, of course - debate and reason is only advanced where participants are willing to hear the questions put to them by the other side and answer them as straightforwardly and as honestly as they can).

Comment: @halfer, but I am putting forward the most unbiassed option there is. That is, *NO* social and political causes to be promoted. You must agree with me there? Bias is when you take a for or an against position. Surely my proposition will help to bring the community together rather than divide it.

Comment: @I.K.: I don't agree with that, but that's by the by. You have thus far avoided answering all the points put to you, and in particular that you have used other people's homophobic opinions (comparison between marriage equality with fascism, for example) but you don't seem to be willing to own up to those opinions. Your willingness to stand by whilst "other people" condemn the LGBT community as "offensive and disgusting" is not healing the rift at all, since you ask.

Comment: You seem to still be ignoring the points I made previously. Even if it's a good idea, even if it could cost them their business, Stack Exchange is in _no way_ required _by anything_ to honor the outcome of the election you call for. You _cannot_ force them to obey the outcome of that election. I'm sorry, but you can't do that.

Comment: @Kendra, I'm not forcing anyone. Let the community have their **full** say on the matter. Let's go from there.

Comment: @Kendra, you just don't get it, do you? Thing that your abhorent attitude doens't helps your agenda at all. You can abuse whatever law to your own profit, but don't be surprised that people feel your gay pride "shoved down their throats" and despise you for THAT, and not for issue itself, as was already mentioned many times in several related discussions.

Comment: @halfer - that's just those "equality for all" guys at their finest - censor everything that doesn't fits their bestest and tolerant-est position. I'd rather let them continue - that shows perfectly who they really are.

Comment: @Oleg: no-one has to tolerate four-letter abuse anywhere on the SE sites - as a 10K user you know this very well. Please post again if you want to be heard. (Your comment just now to Kendra is not an example of civil tolerance either, but it is marginally an improvement. I think it will just about survive moderator flags, but I think you can do better than that.)

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov My entire point is that people _can_ dislike it, and because of that, Stack Exchange _can_ lose business, but aside from stopping business with Stack Exchange there's nothing any of us can really do about decisions like these that they decide to make. I've had zero attitude in this conversation- I am simply trying to explain that Stack Exchange does not have anything forcing them to listen to us. This fact has zero to do with my views on what happened. Stack Exchange can still suffer consequences in the form of people leaving, yes, but we cannot force them to do as we say.

Comment: To sum it up further: You can hold your election on the matter. Your side can even win. But Stack Exchange does not have to listen to your side if, as a private company, they decide they disagree. I'm all for having the community make a decision on this. The problem is just that Stack Exchange does not have to honor that decision.

Comment: @I.K.: it is indeed possible to oppose a logo change for a variety of reasons, and that opposition may be constructive. I furthermore agree that not all opposition to marriage equality is homophobic. But yes, I suspect you personally hold homophobic and intolerant views, I have explained why I think that, and I have given you plenty of chances to explain otherwise. You refuse to do so.

Comment: (I am quite forthright with my opinions, undoubtedly, but I'd point out to you IK, as I've said to Oleg, that abuse isn't helpful in this conversation. You'll note I've not insulted you at all in this or any discussion, and your position will be infinitely strengthened if you can stick to rational argumentation.)

Comment: @halfer _"You'll note I've not insulted you at all in this or any discussion"_ To be fair, there are people who will take accusations of being various "bad things" such as, in this instance, homophobic, as an insult. Even if they are, they may not realize they are (I'm not saying I.K. is, the 'they' is generalized to humans) and openly accusing it can be seen as shining a negative light on them as a person. So in I.K.'s defense, they could very well be insulted and offending by your implication and commenting that they are, in your opinion, homophobic.

Comment: @halfer In other words, your accusing I.K. of being homophobic can very easily be deemed insulting. Not only that, but it can very _very_ easily hurt their reputation.

Comment: @Kendra: I see your point, but it's hard to know what language to use otherwise. I do understand that in general, calling a spade a spade can give one's ideological opponent a handy get-out clause to refuse to converse further (and I assure you that is not my intent in this case). I am rather unhappy that in this instance, IK seems to be advancing exceedingly discriminatory arguments but assigning the blame to "other people". (Myself, I have been called all manner of things on the internet - "racist" many times - and it just bounces off every time).

Comment: @Kendra: if someone compares marriage equality with Nazism, or regards LGBT as "offensive and disgusting", I think that would normally be called homophobic. If there is another way of saying the same thing though, I am genuinely all ears.

Comment: @halfer In some cultures, it's not considered "homophobic" to be against those relationships- It's just considered being a good citizen. And I.K. is correct- The thought of LGBT _is_ offensive to some people. I did not see a spot where I.K. said that it was offensive _to them personally,_ just where they said it could be conceived by some (some Christians for example) as something as offensive as Nazism is to a lot of us. I think you took that comment out of context from them.

Comment: @Kendra, `:-]` heh, you open the discussion out in some very broad ways, and I fear you are allowing IK off the hook he/she has placed themselves upon. It is indeed a fact that some people find LGBT rights offensive, and I think since such folks are afforded the free speech to say so, other people should be afforded the right the demarcate those views as homophobic. Similarly, some countries are anti-gay, but should we limit our speech about such oppression in the name of cultural sensitivity? Tolerance should not be required to be tolerant of intolerance.

Comment: @halfer, I just read your comments and you accusing me of being homophobic. That is insulting. As I said before it doesn't matter what my stance is or yours on LGBT, I'm trying to focus on building the community rather than dividing it. I believe an election will do that on this matter. Kendra, thank you for your comments about me being insulted. I'm trying  to remain impartial here but halfer was trying to degrade the tone of the conversation.

Comment: @I.K.: I am more than happy to retract the word "homophobic" if you will distance yourself from the hateful remarks you have assigned to third parties. I genuinely regret that you are offended by my words: it is not my intention. I do admit to some frustration that you are dancing around the issue, and appear unwilling to give any clear answers at all.

Comment: @halfer, I have made position clear many times. I am only here continuing this conversation so that SE remains site free of promoting any political and social causes whether a user is for them or against them. This has always been my stance. Because this is the most beneficial way to keep the community together, it seems to irk you and you resorted to degrading the conversation by insulting me. However, you have made yourself out to be a LGBT fascist. That's not an insult; just an observation I have made based on your comments on this post.

Comment: Ha @I.K., I think you have no idea what real fascism is. But, fine, we've traded one insult/observation each, so we're fair and square. My point remains: you have drawn attention to other people's discriminatory views, and then attempted to pass off not distancing yourself from that as "community healing". You're sat in Schrödinger's box, and can call yourself both homophobic and not homophobic at the same time. Let us know when you want to, err, come out!

Comment: @halfer, again you have insulted me and want to degrade the conversation.  You have no desire to bring the community together unless it believes in what you believe. Kendra has already pointed out your mistaken view of my stance.

Comment: Not so. For clarification, I am happy for people to have their thoughts on marriage equality (or on any other issue) but people need to take responsibility for their inflammatory speech (even if they attempt to assign it to other people). The right to free speech you have been using -- which is a right I defend -- seeks to strip other people of other rights. I would be genuinely pleased if you would reflect upon that, even if you will not be drawn upon it in a public venue.

Comment: @halfer Are you saying that, because I.K. said that other people find the subject offensive, in reality it is I.K. that finds it offensive and therefore they are trying to hide that they are homophobic? That is... A very absurd logic to use to defend insulting someone. Are you now going to accuse me of the same, since I defended I.K.'s statement that there are people who find LGBT as offensive as Nazism? You are thoroughly derailing the point of I.K.'s answer _which has nothing to do with what they think of LGBT rights_ by assigning to them that which you _do not_ know is true.

Comment: I.K _never once stated_ that they dislike anything about the LGBT movement. In fact, I have seen during the weekend _several people_ that have admitted to being completely for the ruling by the Supreme Court, yet completely against what happened with the logo here. Do _not_ assign false statements to another, as that is rude and can actually harm the reputation of the individual.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @Kendra. No, I am not saying that. I am saying that a pointed and repeated refusal to distance oneself from obviously inflammatory views opens oneself up to the charge of supporting them. I have explicitly said that people opposed to the logo change, and people who oppose marriage equality, are not necessarily homophobic (see above, ~3 hours ago).

Comment: @halfer And I.K. has not _given_ their view of the subject, they have only pointed out that _there are people in the world with that view._ I personally know two of them who find LGBT to be _that_ offensive that they would easily (and have in conversation) compare it to Nazism. I.K. _has no obligation_ to defend themself from you based on _opinions that other people in the world_ hold. You accused them of something you have no proof of based on _opinions other people in the world hold,_ which is not fair, and is rude, to I.K. I have nothing further to say, if you don't get my point this time.

Comment: @Kendra: we respectfully disagree, then.

Comment: @Kendra if I know two people who insist that single-word spelling tests  of a three-letter word are as difficult as Nuclear Physics then they are just spouting wind as they clearly don't even know enough about Nuclear Physics to know that they are massive orders of magnitude away from a rational comparison. If the comparison is allowed to stand, the simple spelling is the difficulty assigned to Nuclear Physics. Equalising the minor to the massively major degrades the concept of the major. It has to.

Comment: @Kendra Sorry, looks like I go the wrong person with that one, not directed at you. I'll kill it. I'm not sure it's even worth redoing. I guess I get annoyed at the fast-and-loose use of terminology. Just taking mass-murder on an enormous scale (out of everything the Nazis did) and then saying that anyone could ever, possibly, remotely, equate the way they feel about "gay-something" with the way that anyone who knows anything about Nazism feels about that. The equation is hyperbole to the point of lying, or for public display of crass idiocy. Whoops. I'd best stop again now.