# Remember when you promised not to imply that I support your political message?

Tags: support, profile-page, licensing, logo

Before [dismissing this as a "spurious interpretation"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297908/what-is-the-policy-for-stack-overflow-and-political-matters-such-as-the-logo-co/297916?noredirect=1#comment212905_297916), please consider that these license restrictions are the same ones that protect our names and technical content from being used on sites that promote white supremacy (fancy some KKK pictures slotted between answers, anyone?  Or maybe used to indicate "accepted answer" or used for upvote and downvote buttons or user flair?), flag burning, protests at military funerals, or whatever offends you, if having five black-robed officials assume for themselves the roles of executive, legislature, and judiciary doesn't<sup>1</sup>.

Ok, I get that Stack Exchange is a private company, and stackoverflow.com is your property, and you can use it to spread your message.

In an extreme case, you could (temporarily I would hope) replace the entire site with a page celebrating the new "rights" of founder Joel.  The community would surely be unhappy with losing access to this great resource, but it would be within your rights.

What's problematic, however, is using Subscriber Content and Subscriber profiles to promote your cause.  You and I and every other subscriber have entered into [a legal agreement](https://stackexchange.com/legal) which grants you certain rights to use content.  That agreement uses the following language to incorporate [a license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode) by reference, which we commonly know as "CC BY-SA 3.0":

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license.

That license has multiple provisions which protect the author of content by ensuring that they receive credit for their work while protecting their personal brand against abuse.  Here's the wording (emphasis mine):

> 4. Restrictions. The license granted in Section 3 above is expressly made subject to and limited by the following restrictions:
>
>    c. **If You Distribute, or Publicly Perform the Work or any Adaptations or Collections**, You must, unless a request has been made pursuant to Section 4(a), keep intact all copyright notices for the Work and provide, reasonable to the medium or means You are utilizing: (i) the name of the Original Author (or pseudonym, if applicable) if supplied, and/or if the Original Author and/or Licensor designate another party or parties (e.g., a sponsor institute, publishing entity, journal) for attribution ("Attribution Parties") in Licensor's copyright notice, terms of service or by other reasonable means, the name of such party or parties; (ii) the title of the Work if supplied; (iii) to the extent reasonably practicable, the URI, if any, that Licensor specifies to be associated with the Work, unless such URI does not refer to the copyright notice or licensing information for the Work; and (iv) , consistent with Ssection 3(b), in the case of an Adaptation, a credit identifying the use of the Work in the Adaptation (e.g., "French translation of the Work by Original Author," or "Screenplay based on original Work by Original Author"). The credit required by this Section 4(c) may be implemented in any reasonable manner; provided, however, that in the case of a Adaptation or Collection, at a minimum such credit will appear, if a credit for all contributing authors of the Adaptation or Collection appears, then as part of these credits and in a manner at least as prominent as the credits for the other contributing authors. For the avoidance of doubt, You may only use the credit required by this Section for the purpose of attribution in the manner set out above and, by exercising Your rights under this License, **You may not implicitly or explicitly assert or imply any connection with, sponsorship or endorsement by the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties, as appropriate, of You or Your use of the Work, without the separate, express prior written permission of the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties.**
>
>    d. Except as otherwise agreed in writing by the Licensor or as may be otherwise permitted by applicable law, **if You Reproduce, Distribute or Publicly Perform the Work either by itself or as part of any Adaptations or Collections, You must not distort, mutilate, modify or take other derogatory action in relation to the Work which would be prejudicial to the Original Author's honor or reputation.** Licensor agrees that in those jurisdictions (e.g. Japan), in which any exercise of the right granted in Section 3(b) of this License (the right to make Adaptations) would be deemed to be a distortion, mutilation, modification or other derogatory action prejudicial to the Original Author's honor and reputation, the Licensor will waive or not assert, as appropriate, this Section, to the fullest extent permitted by the applicable national law, to enable You to reasonably exercise Your right under Section 3(b) of this License (right to make Adaptations) but not otherwise.

These sections clearly apply to Collections, and therefore to stackoverflow.com.

It is indisputable that placing the logo and mouseover text on user profile pages creates a "connection with" the user.  It is also indisputable that written permission has not been obtained from every registered user to create such a connection between their content<sup>2</sup> and the cause which Stack Exchange, Inc. has chosen to publicize/celebrate this weekend.

It is disputable (and probably will be disputed endlessly) whether the presence of the logo and mouseover text on the profile imply "sponsorship or endorsement", but we can probably agree that it is possible that a reasonable person might perceive it as so doing.  Similarly for whether the usage of the logo on Q&A pages where Subscriber Content appears implies a connection.  Most viewers probably agree that including the rainbow logo and mouseover text on Q&A pages "distort" and "modify" the message of the technical content; fewer will consider it to "mutilate" or be a "derogatory action" but these too are not unreasonable.

I'm pointing this out on Meta at this time, rather than via the legal contact form, because I have hope that this matter can be amicably resolved.  In my estimation, Stack Exchange has simply been a little careless about their responsibilities concerning messages which do not represent the views of contributors, and will quickly cure the violation, without need for closing accounts, takedown notices, or stronger legal actions.

My suggestion is that the rainbow logo be immediately removed from user profile pages (all tabs), and that a disclaimer be added to the logo on other pages, in such a fashion that it appears in mouseover text and also when the page is printed, stating that the message represents the viewpoint of Stack Exchange, Inc., but may not reflect the views of individual users.

Whether or not you are OK with having your personal brand used to spread this message, you should be very concerned about the fact that the requirement of a written opt-in was bypassed.  Alternately, Stack Exchange could take more effective steps to clearly separate their speech from association with subscribers and Subscriber Content.

[image]

<sup>1</sup> I realize that most people have chosen a side on this issue without considering the balance of power between the three branches of the USA's government, and it's OK if you have.  But please realize that this ruling is controversial for many reasons and that throwing out words like "discrimination" or "bigot" do not adequately address those reasons.  I personally find that this quote sums up concerns about judicial overreach nicely: "A government big enough to give you everything you want is a government big enough to take from you everything you have." (Gerald Ford)

<sup>2</sup> Even if I upload a different avatar image and use a pseudonym, [as suggested by Bill Woodger](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297908/what-is-the-policy-for-stack-overflow-and-political-matters-such-as-the-logo-co/297916?noredirect=1#comment212742_297916), it will still be my content.  Whether the image is a photo of myself or a geometric figure of my creation makes no difference to the verbiage of the CC BY-SA license, although it might be material to other contracts and laws concerning likenesses of individuals.

---

For what it's worth, here is the specific way in which Stack Overflow's action threatens to harm my reputation (previously mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297908/what-is-the-policy-for-stack-overflow-and-political-matters-such-as-the-logo-co/297916?noredirect=1#comment212424_297916) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297908/what-is-the-policy-for-stack-overflow-and-political-matters-such-as-the-logo-co/297916?noredirect=1#comment212437_297916)):

I consistently support (across the Internet and in real life) an originalist view of Constitutional interpretation.  Therefore associating my work with a celebration of a ruling based on dynamic interpretation, paints me as insincere or a hypocrite.

Comment: There's actually significant irony here, from people who assume that the majority vote dictates whether the minority gets to enjoy the rights promised by the CC BY-SA license.

Comment: The *work* is your *post*. Your work has not been modified in *any* way shape or form (although IANAL).

Comment: Can we have an opt-out feature from the ribbon

Comment: @hichris123: Did you read *all* bolded sections of the license?  It concerns both an *implied connection* / *impled association*, and is clearly made to apply to *Collections*.

Comment: `It is indisputable that placing the logo and mouseover text on user profile pages creates a "connection with" the user.`  - No it isn't. It is clearly a site wide logo not one selected by the user.

Comment: They changed their logo, they didn't change the avatar on your usercard to imply your support for everyone now being able to marry a gay

Comment: @MartinSmith: Please note that the wording separately mentions "connection", "association", and "endorsement".  Furthermore, a visitor who isn't highly familiar with SO may, even as they realize that it is a site-wide logo, mistakenly assume that the logo was in place when I chose to establish an account, and thereby wrongly infer that I agree with it.  There is no doubt that a connection has been created.

Comment: Your usercard does not contain the logo. Unless it does, in which case you are misrepresenting yourself

Comment: @random: Oh, you aren't using "usercard" as shorthand for "user profile page"?  Do you mean the signature block?

Comment: The slogan is nonsense. Unless it is an "official" slogan associated with the case or campaign for the case, I think most people won't realise the deeper connection. I've always been able to do what the slogan says, apart from already being married. Pretend it is two days ago, and just read it how it how the words appear, without external interpretation. I'd guess most people looking at your profile, and hovering, in this few days, would do that.

Comment: @Bill: It's a quote from a Joe Biden speech (or so the news reports, can't find transcript).

Comment: As for your consistent support of your views, I don't think realistically that many looking at your profile during this period would draw the conclusion you suggest. People who know you or hold the same views will realise it is just a website you have no personal control over. Other people won't have the remotest clue.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks. Search-enginineing now. Which side was Biden on? I'll probably discover.

Comment: @BillWoodger: Well, my views really don't matter in this discussion.  Stack Exchange would equally, according to CC BY-SA, have to obtain my written permission before adding pro-life material to my profile page in a way that implied a connection to me.

Comment: Why would a visitor viewing your user profile - that clearly states you have been a member for  6 years, 1 month assume that the logo (inspired by a court decision yesterday) was in place when you chose to establish an account?

Comment: @MartinSmith: And from looking at my profile page, or any Q&A page containing one of my answers, how exactly would you determine that the logo was added recently?  Putting the logo on the site may have been inspired by the court decision, but the use of the rainbow is much much older.

Comment: But I thought your "reputational" claim was based on the "celebration of a ruling" and that was yesterday. Are you saying that you would be against the rainbow logo in any circumstance?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Judicial activism has been around a lot longer than just yesterday.  And closely associated with that rainbow.

Comment: @BenVoigt so what's the problem, exactly?

Comment: @BenVoigt oh, I see; you could have mentioned that! I was going by the large picture **in this question**.

Comment: Personally, I fail to see how anyone would confuse the logo of the site with anything in your profile or posts, or from the logo infer that you support the message. To me, this is making a huge *huge* mountain out of a molehill.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Well, that is what Stack Exchange changed my profile page to.  They didn't exactly give me warning that I was going to need to edit a disclaimer into it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Assume that a viewer reached my profile page directly, either through Google or one of the links on other sites, and hasn't visited any other page of SO (ok, that's absurd, who hasn't visited SO.  Instead, assume they haven't visited any other page of SO since the new logo was added -- that's possibly even worse, since MY PAGE appears DIFFERENT what what they're used to seeing).  Up until now, my SO profile has been a valuable part of my personal brand, so there are links out there.

Comment: @BenVoigt because you didn't need to edit a disclaimer into it. I simply **do not** understand how you think anyone would draw the conclusion that you support gay marriage specifically or dynamic interpretation of the constitution generally from your membership of a site that has temporarily altered its logo. I also find it hard to believe that anyone who describes themselves as *"[a consistent supporter of] an originalist view of Constitutional interpretation"* would find a small rainbow to be particularly embarrassing, but I suppose that's a separate discussion.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: You are aware that the logo comes with mouseover text?

Comment: Yes, I am; so what? It doesn't say *"Ben Voigt is a hypocrite"*.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to check whether you were thinking that the "small rainbow" was somehow ambiguous as to meaning.

Comment: @MartinSmith: So just to be clear, the point you are trying to make against my argument is that it's unlikely that anyone will find an implication that I support judicial activism, because in your opinion, the implication is that I support homosexual marriage?  You realize whether the logo and its mouseover text on my profile page implies one, the other, both, or the meaning ascribed to rainbows in Genesis, makes no difference.  I am against having Stack Exchange attach any sociopolitical message to my online brand without my permission.

Comment: @ben I personally don't think people would assume either. Any more than they would make that inference from usage of github,twitter,American airlines or any other company that has used a rainbow logo in the last day.

Comment: Well, reading your profile, I'm not quite sure: Are you unhappy about the endorsement of *any* political message (even the association is tenuous, "endorsement" is really beyond reaching), are you unhappy with the supreme court decision irrespective of rationale, are you unhappy about the methodology of their rationale, or don't you concurr that the rationale leads to that decision?

Comment: So in essence you don't support marrying a developer who may or may not like rainbow coloured icons?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Like I said in my last comment, "I am against having Stack Exchange attach any sociopolitical message to my online brand without my permission."  Since it seems no one is going to give me peace until I reveal my thoughts on "civil rights for homosexual Americans", I will say two things:  First, I am against the federal government seizing control of the definition of marriage from the states, even if all three branches agreed, except through the amendment process.  Second, the whole "hospital visitation" thing is compelling, and the fact that these rights are available outside

Comment: of a marriage only by filing hundreds of legal documents is absurd and benefits only lawyers, who get paid for document preparation time.  I am 100% in favor of a streamlined process for two adults of sound mind to agree to a partnership of mutual emotional and financial support that gives visitation rights, pensions, shared property, etc, etc.  And the couple being involved in a sexual relationship should not be a requirement (as some domestic partnership forms evidently demand).  Make it available to lovers, army buddies, parent/child, siblings, and everyone else.

Comment: The usercard is the box bottom right of your posts. The profile page is the content from the Profile tab to the top of the footer block. Your profile sits on the same page as the logo, but does not include the logo

Comment: @random: The mouseover text says "Marry whomever you love."  I don't agree (and probably neither do you), I support quite a number of restrictions concerning consanguinity, age, consent, mental state.  (It shouldn't need to be said, but yes, also restrictions on species and number of parties)  Most of these restrictions are not particularly controversial.  Whether or not I support recognition of same-sex marriages is not actually relevant, the issue is that Stack Exchange has added a statement of support to various pages where my content appears, including my profile page.

Comment: @BenVoigt: and what if people see this as a **positive** thing? You are projecting your own interpretation of the logo onto others. Perhaps you should trust people more? And the majority of people do not live in isolation. The demographic that visits SO also visits Google, GitHub, Bitbucket, Twitter, etc. etc. etc. Chances that someone comes across *just* your profile and makes that leap are ridiculously small.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You asked "What if people see this as a positive thing?"  The license STILL applies and still requires written opt-in before creating a connection between a message, negative or positive, and my content.  See [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298004/remember-when-you-promised-not-to-imply-that-i-support-your-political-message?noredirect=1#comment212976_298004) and [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298004/remember-when-you-promised-not-to-imply-that-i-support-your-political-message?noredirect=1#comment212942_298004)

Comment: @BenVoigt: I was not discussing your legal theory, Jaydles addresses that. I am questioning why you are getting so worked up over this.

Comment: @BenVoigt I personally think you've drawn 100x more attention to yourself by getting all worked up and making numerous posts about it. YES, you're upset, you have a right to be upset, but really... people aren't assuming your gay just because S.O changed THEIR logo for a few days man. Try and chill out.  You have every right to cancel your account if you don't agree with how you're being treated or if you don't agree with the views of S.O.

Comment: @enki.dev: There are lots of users who don't want Stack Overflow used for political purposes, and even more who would opt-in if given the chance, but don't like that they have no choice in the matter.  I've found that I'm able to enunciate the particular objection, apart from the political flashpoint, much better than most (last time around, the objection was using SO meta for recruitment, the flashpoint was sexism), so if the price of having a real conversation instead of name-calling is that I have to be in the middle of it, so be it.

Comment: Maybe somebody should cross-post this to the Law StackExchange...

Comment: @BenAaronson: Probably, since the response from Stack Exchange chose to avoid rendering the hoped-for opinion on the moral ramifications of adding political speech to profile pages.  (This is why I chose Meta rather than the official legal contact)  For obvious reasons, I don't expect an admission of legal wrongdoing from an SE employee; but I thought they might concede that user profile pages establish a stronger implied link than they intended.

Comment: @BenVoigt why did you not object to the old logo - that was suggesting you were endorsing SO was it not? Also, please get a lawyer, it would be interesting to see what they say.

Comment: I think a simple technical solution could be replacing the rainbow logo/hover text with the original version **on profile pages**. Indeed coming to the profile page directly from an external link could give the impression of an association of Ben with a celebration of the ruling.

Comment: @6502 Sure, but that is not really a solution. "Stack Overflow" will still appear on Ben's profile page, and a hypothetical visitor might associate (1) Ben with SO and (2) SO with its public position on a political issue and hence (3) Ben with that position. Since the position has already been taken, the only solution is that Ben may fully brand all appearances of his content as he pleases, exclusively on benvoigt.com as opposed to Stack Overflow, since surely visitors can read the URL and infer things about him. (In other words, I think the "problem" is not cogent, much less a legal issue.)

Comment: @Frank: If Ben doesn't want to be associated to SO it can delete its profile. IIUC Ben doesn't want to be associated with the celebration for something he doesn't agree on. I think it's ok that SO celebrates (yay!) ... I also think however that indeed if someone comes to Ben's profile directly from an external link it could be tricked into thinking that Ben is celebrating too. Ben solved this misunderstanding by changing its profile text but I think it's true that this trap is easy to fall in and therefore, by default, I think it would have been better to keep a regular logo on profile pages.

Comment: @6502 Okay. But that scenario is premised on a connection that *might* be drawn by a very specific hypothetical person. If we're instead going to speak of what some person I dream up *might* infer, why draw the line at rainbows? If Ben's argument held any water, he would be entitled to silence the entire SE staff (since any of their words could be viewed as a statement by SE, and hence by Ben), even if he isn't asking to go so far as to make that demand in this case. The simplicity of his "remedy" does not in any way amend the faults in his argument.

Comment: [cont.] And that is why he has abandoned the argument and has retreated to something like "Isn't this too much bother? Just cave, why don't you, or stay silent next time?" Here's the quote from below: "Even though you feel that those sections of the license don't technically apply here, is making changes to our personal profile pages worth the user dissatisfaction?"

Comment: @Frank that is not an abandonment of the argument. Showing that a conclusion can be reached without relying on a contested premise is a common approach.

Comment: @BenVoigt Substitute "argument" for "premise" and that description seems more apposite. You're bargaining at this point, no longer making the case, from what I can see. And dismissing someone's very clear point as "not passing the smell test"? Okay, go ahead; that's an excellent way to be taken seriously.

Comment: @Frank I fail to see how words of Stack Exchange could be misconstrued as representing me if, as I suggested, they added a clarification that the statement represents Stack Exchange Inc (or the individual employee), and not the users, which type of disclaimer is found very often these days, to the point where lacking it becomes a strong suggestion to the contrary. Or did you not read the complete post?

Comment: @Frank again, providing reasoning that doesn't use a contested premise (or line of argument, if you prefer) does not mean that the original premise is false, it means that even if it were, there is still a point to be made.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that an argument is not false simply because it is abandoned. Regarding the proposed clarification/disclaimer: you are again referring to your remedy, not to the problem. I think your claim that you are facing a new problem here is not legitimate. If you find it problematic that a rainbow should appear on Stack Exchange (because of the political associations it and the hover text have), how much worse would it be if Stack Exchange itself came to mean something in the public sphere? Would you have a legal right to tell them what to do in that case?

Comment: Anyway, I am sympathetic to the request in the context of the points made by Adam Davis. The legal arguments here seems pretty weak (though obviously IANAL) and distract from the real reasons why SO should consider the support request. (The implicit threat and mention of your political beliefs are also a distraction, though the latter probably couldn't be avoided.)

Comment: @Frank I agree it it much better to approach this from a perspective other than legal obligation. Consider the quotes from the license to show the spirit of the relationship between users and Stack Exchange - I would not have posted a legal demands notice on Meta, which again, I already said in the original post. As for whether Stack Exchange itself came to mean something new, I would have to evaluate whether my relationship with them (which is real, not misconstrued) could continue. However even then, they could only state the facts of my associating with them, and not imply

Comment: a connection between me and their political speech. (Where "could not" also means "should not, and could not without violating the spirit of the agreement and the trust users placed in them to speak truthfully", without addressing the legal permissibility)

Comment: Let me be clear: I am not against Stack Exchange making factual statements about my relationship with them, including the ones that appear on my profile such as when I joined and how many parts I have made. I am against them attaching sociopolitical statements to my work in such a way as implies a false connection between those statements and myself. It is only the perception that the statements represent me that I am fighting.

Comment: Just wanted to make it clear that I'm not a lawyer (I don't even like lawyers and I don't even read those screenfuls before clicking "I accept") but I don't think there is any reason for which SO couldn't have changed its logo. I think it was 100% within its choices to change the logo and I even actually like it did (for example I discovered about the ruling just because of that logo). What I'm saying is that SO could have kept the change only for the front page or just not on profile pages and doing a better service to everyone doing so.

Comment: I always laugh at the great rethoric lengths *some people* are willing to go just to argue against equality on some asinine technicalities. This post of yours is **way more harmful to your reputation** than StackOverflow having a site-wide colored logo.

Comment: @Rene you could actually read Jaydles last paragraph where he thoroughly debunks your claim that I "argue against equality".  Your attempt to redirect the discussion is thoroughly unhelpful.

Comment: Ben, though I had not had time to thoroughly read the post until now, as I had said in the comments of my answer, I am glad to have read it. Though after reading through the terms myself, I disagree this is (well, was) a violation of the terms. (For reasons already thoroughly discussed here.) I do appreciate how well you wrote out your side of the debate and thank you for linking the post on my answer so that I could read it.

Comment: The owners of SO should take this seriously - the answers here are not from lawyers, and this is a matter dissenting people feel very strongly about.  I had the exact same reaction as Ben Voigt and do not appreciate that my contributions have suddenly been associated with an event I strongly disagree with on multiple levels.

Comment: _"My online brand"_... Ben, you're taking your profile way too damn seriously. If you're worried about your reputation, you've already gone and ruined it for a lot of people, with this thread... I wonder, have you posted something like this on _every_ site you use that has a rainbow logo?

Comment: Thank you for that screen shot, Ben! I filched my avatar from it.

Comment: I find this whole discussion baffling. My first thought is that if you had left well alone, your name wouldn't have been associated with this in any way. and any affiliation you think you have had thrust upon you would have gone away. Now this is all on Google for eternity. Secondly, the fact that this in any way damages your "online brand" makes me roll my eyes. Even if this were true, I wouldn't want to be associated with people who thought that way.

Comment: How, if at all, is this different from "I do not want to be associated with an ad on this page" or "I do not want to be associated with a question in the hot network sidebar"?

Comment: @BenVoigt Ben, I've always respected you as a programmer and will continue to do so. I find myself deeply disappointed that http://www.stackoverflow.com has placed you in a position where your only recourse for not supporting a political agenda is to make a political statement such as this one. I would like to add that I respect your logical approach but I fear I am not in the majority, as any statement that disagrees with the US Supreme Courts decision is construed as "homophobic".

Comment: There is some serious irony in you combating perceived (and imaginary) damage to your "brand" by coming here and doing actual damage to it.

Comment: "...having five black-robed officials assume for themselves the roles of executive, legislature, and judiciary doesn't..." First of all, have some respect for the Supreme Court. You're painting them like Harry Potter villains. Secondly, they assumed for the themselves the role of the judiciary. If you're going to attempt to make a legalistic argument, the least you could do is understand the role of SCOTUS in our government. It's impossible to take anything you wrote seriously after that - it's just, to borrow a phrase, jiggery-pokery.

Comment: @Barry when the other four justices describe the decision as encroaching on legislative powers, you cannot call my opinion uninformed.

Comment: @Cerbrus I wouldn't use the term "brand" myself except that it is the commonly used word for this.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I wasn't aware that that's the commonly used term. (Native language is Dutch). Learned something today :-)

Comment: @Ulrich sites that fail to mark ads with "ADVERTISEMENT" often confuse visitors, to the point where projects actually leave Sourceforge over it (I can link references if you like). I hope Stack Exchange is not among those (I don't know because I haven't visited without being logged in).

Comment: @BenVoigt Sure I can. The majority ruled that it's within their powers to do so, therefore it is. That's how it works. It's literally their job to make that decision. It's also utterly irrelevant to the question of the logo, so it comes off as pretty unhinged.

Comment: @barry You just made my point

Comment: @BenVoigt I made your point that you come across as unhinged? I'm glad you agree with me there. It's a LOGO dude, get over yourself.

Comment: @TimothyShields Neither are the claims that this is somehow not allowed.

Comment: @Barry: You didn't say that the Constitution granted SCOTUS jurisdiction.  You didn't say that Congress passed (and the President signed) a law giving SCOTUS jurisdiction here.  You said (quite correctly) that SCOTUS wrote an opinion giving themselves jurisdiction, which is exactly my point.  They bypassed the other two branches of government, not just according to me, but according to your own comment.  It's sad that you know exactly what happened, and you still can't see that it is wrong.

Comment: @TonyK: BTW, you can get a higher resolution version straight from [the source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297859/103167).

Comment: @BenVoigt The majority ruled that the 14th amendment grants a fundamental right to marriage. SCOTUS does not need a hall pass from either of the other two branches to interpret constitutional amendments. It wouldn't be a particularly independent branch of government if it did. Perhaps the issue is that for all your claims of originalism and loving the constitution, you just don't like the outcome - so you decided therefore that it must be illegitimate.

Comment: @BenVoigt You're more than welcome to dislike SCOTUS outcomes (I dislike many of them myself), just as you're more than welcome for some reason to still keep that surreal disclaimer on your profile page longer after the reason for it has gone, but to claim it *illegitimate* is more than a little sad.

Comment: @Barry So are you recanting your previous comment that they have the power to decide this case because they ruled that they do, in favor of some other source of jurisdiction? Because as it stands, your words support my point not yours.

Comment: "It is indisputable that placing the logo and mouseover text on user profile pages creates a "connection with" the user." Yes it is disputable. I don't see it creating a connection with the user at all. The only connection the user has is to the site, not to whatever logo the site uses. BTW, part of the Constitution mentions "No state shall make or enforce any law which shall abridge the privileges or immunities of citizens of the United States; nor shall any state deprive any person [...] within its jurisdiction the equal protection of the laws."

Comment: The case here is simply that you have inferred something which was not implied. Therefore the whole case is moot.

Comment: I think your passport photo looks really nice under a rainbow.

Comment: @MartinSmith I had the impression from the screenshot that Ben had written "Marry whomever you love. ..." and so forth. Do you think a judge who is unfamiliar with the network might form a similar opinion?

Comment: My take-away: Regardless of intent, from the comments and answers, it's clear that people aren't really buying the whole I'm-actually-not-a-homophobe argument. Now if that someone actually weren't a homophobe, they probably wouldn't want to be associated with the content that makes them look like one, and would ask to be disassociated from it. Otherwise, all that wouldn't really be an issue for them, and they might instead insist were right all along and keep showing it around to people. In this case, said user has kept in on their profile for 3+ years. Sums it up for me.

Comment: Nice example of the [Streisand effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect). I had never knew about this icon if OP didnt try to remove it. Well done SO. Thank you for trying to make the world a better place :)

Comment: Imagine being this angry about people being nice to other people. Being nice to people is not "politics". Getting angry about being nice to people is also not "politics". It's just being, well, not nice to people.

Answer (score 125):

Normally, I try to focus on what's fair, appropriate, etc. to everyone, but this question is really about legal questions, so I'll try to focus on that. Even though I'm not a lawyer, so you should get your own if you really need legal advice. :)

The short version:
**Legally speaking, the CC-SA license does not give contributors any veto power over our name, logo, catchphrases, tee shirt designs, or font choice.**

The clauses you're quoting don't do what you're suggesting.  Here's the first:

> You may not implicitly or explicitly assert or imply any connection with, sponsorship or endorsement by the Original Author...

This means that we can't do things that say, "Ben Endorses...". It would likely cover actions such as us saying "Ben endorses Stack Overflow," or being sneaky bastards, and taking some quote from your post saying,

> "originalist view of Constitutional interpretation? I love it!"

... and then just excerpting the "I love it! - Ben" and using it in an ad for Stack Overflow, which would imply you endorsed *us*.

But your argument is dependent on the assumption that that just by having anything in our header (a name, logo, and tooltip, say) we've done something to imply you endorse all those things, whatever they happen to say, even when you didn't have an issue with them.  Before, it would mean you endorsed us, our name, the font we used, orange, etc. That's... pretty certainly not right, since it literally would mean any website with a header can't use CC-SA without constantly violating it.

As to the second clause you cited:

> You must not distort, mutilate, modify or take other derogatory action in relation to the Work which would be prejudicial to the Original Author's honor or reputation

Others in the comments touched on the what's wrong there - it's about mutilating the *work*. It doesn't assign control over other parts of the site, page, etc.  If an *edit* does things that can be demonstrated convincingly to a judge to harm your reputation, you've got a strong legal case.   If we start running taglines on the top of the page saying, "Stack Overflow - the website that kills puppies!" you don't have much of a legal case.

**Couple more minor legal clarifications:**

- "Reasonable person" has different meanings in different fields of law, but none that I know of allow for the *possibility* that a reasonable person might think something.  They're all related to what a reasonable person is *likely* to think. As in, "Is it likely that the average reasonable person will think Ben approves of our logo colors, politics, or hairstyle, assuming we depict them all in our wesite header?"
- CC-SA does not in any case grant one the right to *remove* their work. It's always been the option to anonymize in certain circumstances.  (To be fair, you didn't suggest otherwise in your post, but I saw it touched on in other answers or comments.)

One note, in case it helps: We have no position on whether this use of judicial power was constitutionally... anything. Our support was entirely for the result, and it's possible that some day, over a beer, you'd easily convince me that despite my support for the outcome, that the court was the wrong place for it to happen. I'm honestly embarrassed that I lack the background to have an opinion on that.

Oh, and one last thing: Ben has taken a legal position (which I disagreed with) and expressed a constitutional opinion (which I've no opinion of). Let's steer clear of making assumptions about his feelings toward any group; his post does not necessarily imply any disrespect for anyone.

Comment: Couple things -- you gave an example of "explicit" endorsements, while the license clearly also includes implied connections, sponsorships, and endorsements, and those aren't limited to your "sneaky" example.  Then, I think it's reasonable to say that when I signed up for a user account, I authorized a certain connection between myself and Stack Overflow.  The change to the logo, and especially adding the mouseover text, dramatically changed the nature of that connection, such that it isn't covered by my earlier agreement.

Comment: Finally, are you saying that our content can be used under CC BY-SA by whomever, however, as long as they link back to SO?  Because I don't think it is acceptable to intermingle our technical contributions with (whatever the offensive image of the week is) without clearly disclaiming that the combination is made by the other site and does not represent the opinions of the original authors.

Comment: @BenVoigt other people can (and do) use content from SO, including various sites that effectively mirror the content; all that the license requires is that they provide a link back to the original. To use your opening example, your answer *could* be used on a white-supremacist site and they would be  *required* to provide a link back to you as attribution (see e.g. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).

Comment: Explicit or implicit, it still requires that most reasonable folks believe that ALL users "endorse" the name, logo, art, colors, catchphrases, etc. in the header of every site using CC-SA.  (Which also means we're all in constant violation of it.) You could ask a lawyer, but I think that one's pretty clear.

Comment: And no, CC BY-SA doesn't grant the right to demand removal of work, nor do I mean to suggest that it does.  As copyright owner I automatically have that right -- your right to use my content without my continuing permission is wholly dependent on a perpetual grant of the CC BY-SA license.  If the license is violated, you'd have to remove content when I, as copyright holder, choose to assert my rights (there's a whole takedown request process -- Yuck!).  I do NOT want to go down that path.  Which I already said in the original post.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Indeed, they would have to provide an attribution, and they could use the content as long as they abide by CC BY-SA, and particularly that requires that "You may not implicitly or explicitly assert or imply any connection with, sponsorship or endorsement by the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties, as appropriate, of You or Your use of the Work, without the separate, express prior written permission of the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties."

Comment: @BenVoigt, I'm not quite saying *any* mingling is okay.  For example, if some site published your post and usercard with links back (so they ARE attributing properly),  but edited a swastika onto the card itself, you'd likely  have some legal argument, because they did things that made it look to most people like YOU endorse some nazi thing. But a Nazi website re-using your stuff probably couldn't be stopped, as long as they don't do anything likely to imply to most people that you endorse them specifically.

Comment: @Jaydles: Ok, then look again at just how close the political message is to my name and image on the profile page, and consider whether that might be a little too close for comfort and whether profile pages of individual users might not be the best place for this (or at least, it should be opt-in based).  Even though you feel that those sections of the license don't technically apply here, is making changes to our personal profile pages worth the user dissatisfaction?  (On the one hand, I realize the profile automatically changed with everything else, on the other hand, it wouldn't be

Comment: difficult to leave the normal logo on profiles... an opt-in/opt-out mechanism is obviously a much higher implementation cost)

Comment: @BenVoigt: the DMCA takedown procedure is for when a *third party copyright* has been violated, where whomever posted the content did not have the right to do so. Don't confuse that with content being posted that is wholly yours to enter into the agreement.

Comment: I brought my complaint and suggested fix here because I hoped that sanity would prevail, someone would take one look and go "Oh, we really didn't intend for this to go on user profiles and upset people", and everyone would be back to asking difficult C++ questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It applies where there is no agreement.  Either because the person who posted has no right to enter an agreement, or because the license terms weren't followed, terminating the agreement.

Comment: @BenVoigt: the moment you post, you agree to the terms. There is no backsies here, you cannot go *oh, no, I don't agree anymore*. That's not how it works. If you think it works otherwise, I suggest you either consult a lawyer and stop posting altogether until you can verify that your interpretation holds any water.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I understand that the license is *perpetual*.  That's not the same as *unconditional*.  This is covered in section 7 of the license.

Comment: @BenVoigt: the *Stack Exchange Terms of Service* use the word *irrevocably*.

Comment: @BenVoigt sanity *is* prevailing, you just disagree with the outcome.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: *irrevocably* is also not the same as *unconditionally*.  The license still terminates if and when section 7 says it does.

Comment: From what I know, licensing != giving away and licensing != selling, so licenses are inherently revocable. I don't think that something can be _irrevocably licensed_. Especially, if there are _conditions_.

Comment: @beerwin Your understanding of this is incorrect. Licenses in the US can be revoked after 35 years, but they can be irrevocable until then.

Answer (score 54):

You seem to have helpfully pointed out, through bold text, why your argument isn't even internally consistent:

> You may not implicitly or explicitly assert or imply any connection with, sponsorship or endorsement by the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties, as appropriate, of You or Your use of the Work, without the separate, express prior written permission of the Original Author, Licensor and/or Attribution Parties.

StackExchange isn't allowed to imply that you endorse them. And yet, they've flagrantly shown their logo on your user page since the moment you signed up! So either:

- Showing a logo on your user page (and above your questions/answers) doesn't imply endorsement by you of that logo, or
- StackExchange has consistently been violating the license for most/all of the time it's existed, for every single user, and up until now nobody has noticed and complained. And when you did choose to complain, you needlessly complicated it with a red herring about gay marriage, and offered a "solution" which wouldn't fix anything.

So, which is it?

Comment: Signing up provided my permission to be associated with Stack Overflow in certain ways.  On Friday, Stack Exchange began using my content to imply endorsement of an entirely different event, without obtaining permission. That goes contrary to common sense, moral rights concerning my personal brand, and also the guarantees of the license. It shouldn't even be necessary for the license to enter into this, Stack Exchange should have avoided implications connecting individual users to its new position. But to claim that the new use of my work is completely equivalent to the old use?

Comment: That just doesn't pass the smell test, nor does your answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt Sure, and if this question had been "I feel vaguely aggrieved", then that would be fine. But if you want to make a legal claim, some basic logical consistency is required. SE is no more allowed to imply you endorse them than that you endorse gay marriage. It's simple, straightforward, and there in black and white

Comment: Not exactly.  Stack Exchange isn't allowed to imply a connection, sponsorship, or endorsement between myself and them without my prior express permission.  I did give them permission to create a profile page for me to contain my work, name, and image, by signing up for an account.  But now they're using my work, name, and image in close proximity to a sociopolitical statement, without the usual disclaimer clarifying who the statement speaks for, without obtaining a separate permission for that use.  That violates my moral rights to control my brand, and I think it also violates the license.

Comment: Now, it is quite possible that the permission I provided by signing up for an account falls short of "express prior written permission" required by the license, in which case their placement of the normal logo on my profile page could also be a violation.  I'm neither disputing their right to continue displaying the logo in a way that's substantially equivalent to the profile page which existing when I signed up, nor am I stating any opinion that they have met the license obligations in that regard.  I *am* saying that addition of a politically-charged logo and mouseover text creates a

Comment: very different implication which is not covered by any permission I have given, whether prior or not, express or not, written or not.  All I am asking is that they remove the implication, which can be accomplished by removing the political message, or clarifying that it does not represent individual users, or some combination thereof (for example, complete removal from user profile pages, and disclaimer linked from other pages where the message appears)

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, I understand that you're disputing only the rainbow logo and not the normal one. That's what I'm pointing out is inconsistent.

Comment: @BenVoigt And this explanation about how oh, maybe it's kinda *more* in violation of the license to imply endorsement of a political stance than of a company (even though the license makes no mention of that) and maybe you kinda gave them written permission to say you endorse them when you signed up even though you clearly didn't... that seems a lot less convincing than "displaying a logo doesn't imply endorsement", which coincidentally seems to be the conclusion that this site, Wikipedia, etc. have come to.

Comment: You are aware that right now, there is not "just a logo", correct ?  If you could discover what the rainbow meant only by clicking through to another page, that would be a perfect place for a disclaimer that would trivially solve this. But currently the political speech is directly on my profile page, in the main portion not the header, where everything else is directly related to my account and contributions. I definitely think it is misleading and implies my support.

Comment: Note that I don't have to say that "Stack Exchange had previously been following the license to the letter and every last jot and tittle", in order to say that now, they have violated the spirit of that agreement and probably also the letter.

Comment: You are presenting a [false dichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma). The normal SO logo clearly makes no association with any controversial issue.  So naturally no one has complained about it appearing above his user profile.  The modified SO logo clearly makes a statement in favor of the SCOTUS outcome and gay "marriage."  So naturally people strongly opposed to those things are complaining now.

Comment: @TimothyShields It's not a false dichotomy- the second option is exactly what you stated, that SO has always been in violation of its license but nobody has complained until now. And if this is the case, then his proposed solution is indeed irrelevant- SO would be no less in violation of the license after changing the logo back.

Comment: @TimothyShields But really, the idea that this site, and other sites that publish content under CC BY-SA like Wikipedia have been flagrantly in violation of their license for years and it just hasn't come up seems pretty ludicrous. Wikipedia for example regularly posts banners asking for money and even did their (political) anti-SOPA campaign. The idea that they've been implicitly telling us that every single one of their users endorses their fundraising and political activism and none of their lawyers, and nobody who minds has noticed, seems hard to believe.

Answer (score 26):

The links at the bottom of all of the pages have always pointed to this text:

> Stack Exchange, Inc. does not discriminate in employment matters on
>   the basis of race, color, religion, gender, national origin, age,
>   military service eligibility, veteran status, sexual orientation,
>   marital status, disability, or any other protected class. We support
>   workplace diversity.

So the site has *always* taken a public position in this area. So, you are arguing that temporarily changing the logo colors connects you to view about 'sexual orientation' and 'marital status' in a way that an explicit statement in actual English does not. That seems rather far-fetched to me.

Comment: In that statement the speaker is very clear. Which is what I have requested in regard to the rainbow logo and mouse over text.

Comment: The day a reasonable person thinks a site logo is under any user control, or that your brand includes another entity's trademark and/or dress is the day "you violated my rights" makes any sense

Comment: Incidentally, I agree with the full text that you quoted—but wish to point out that agreement with it does not imply a belief that marriage (between a man and a woman) and partnership (between two people of the same sex) must not be distinguished by using different terms.  (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd)  There is a non-negligible population who don't object to people living whatever lifestyle of their choosing (including sexual relations and financial co-support), but who *do* object to what they perceive as a "hijacking" of the label "marriage" to apply to relationships that cannot produce a continuation of the race through procreation.  So your reasoning is specious; the public position you cite does not equate to or even imply the concepts declared by the mouseover text that @BenVoigt is objecting to.  How important is this?  That's a different question.

Comment: @Wildcard It is not a "lifestyle". A lifestyle is what pub you go to or what clothes you wear or what music you listen to. _Who you are_ is not a "lifestyle". I cannot emphasise that enough.

Answer (score 21):

The best way to resolve this issue is to email team@stackexchange.com with the following request:

> Dear Sir or Madam,
>
> I link to my user page in many ways, directing others to it for personal and professional reasons. The recent logo change supporting a political or social cause on my user page unfortunately has the side effect of making my audience believe I support a specific cause or political agenda.
>
> As we've seen recently [programmers are being fired](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBrendan_Eich&ei=_9iOVeeiNcGbNtbwgbgH&usg=AFQjCNGZXJskJocm57mDEGQ5LAqLl9kCMA&sig2=LViLckwmncXY4OtfvSPQ8Q) for espousing or expressing, even privately, a specific set of social or political beliefs.
>
> I wish to be neutral in my professional life, and as such find that this logo is causing a problem.  I cannot simply remove the links at this time - even if I could find all the web links and forums I've used it in, I cannot recall emails I've included it in.
>
> As such I regretfully request that you delete my account and assign all my posts to an anonymous user account, per your policy.
>
> This affects my account(s) as follows.  You'll note that I've edited my user page to say "DELETE ME".
>
> ...list of links to user pages of users you want deleted...
>
> Thank you for your time and assistance.

For my part, I'll wait several hours and see if either I change my mind, or the site changes its position before I do this.

Comment: Unacceptable.  I should not have to choose between having credit for my content and protecting my brand.  The CC BY-SA license under which I chose to contribute that content guarantees both.  So, if Stack Exchange proves unreasonable now that diamond moderators are aware of my complaint, and I have to send such a request, it will include the removal, not anonymization, of my contributions.

Comment: Other than anonymization vs removal, however, I do like your phrasing.

Comment: BTW, if anyone knows a convenient way to archive my contributions, either using the cc-wiki-dump or Data Explorer, I'd appreciate some pointers.

Comment: [You're welcome](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/csv/426068) @BenVoigt

Comment: @rene: Thank you very much, looks like that takes care of (latest revision of) all the text content.

Comment: The PostHistory table has all the edit/retags etc, in case you want that as well but I leave it to you to [fork the basis](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/329853/ben-voigt-posts) and improve from there... (but I rather don't see you go).

Comment: Account deletion is on a 24 hour timer after manual activation by an SE employee, and the logo is only changed for the weekend. The deletion is unlikely to happen before the regular logo is restored.

Comment: @rene: So do I, that's why I wrote above that "I'm pointing this out on Meta at this time, rather than via the legal contact form, because I have hope that this matter can be amicably resolved. In my estimation, Stack Exchange has simply been a little careless about their responsibilities concerning messages which do not represent the views of contributors, and will quickly cure the violation, without need for closing accounts, takedown notices, or stronger legal actions."

Comment: Better Link for  _programmers are being fired_ (IMHO): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich#Mozilla

Comment: Eich didn't really lose his job as a *programmer*, he lost his position as chief executive of a very unique corporation.

Comment: Eich actually stepped down and resigned according to jkd's link, apparently realizing he could not be an effective leader.

Answer (score 20):

Since my comment on another question generated this question, I'll answer.

First some preliminaries:

- I am a computational physicist, not a lawyer, so any opinions
  expressed on legal issues are those of a layperson.
- I will not discuss my personal opinion on the SCOTUS decision as I
  see it as largely irrelevant to the question at hand.
- It should go without saying, but I am not affiliated with
  StackExchange in any capacity and I do not speak for them. I am just
  another user and my opinions are my own.

What I am failing to see is how exactly, the OP of this question is materially harmed by the expression by StackExchange of an opinion on a political issue that is congruent with that of what is, now, a growing majority of Americans.

The OP may not like that fact, and , particularly in the USA, is free to express his dissent with that growing majority opinion in myriad ways.

But IMO he has failed to show professional harm to himself because  StackExchange has chosen to express a political opinion with which he disagrees.

That the OP is a "Constitutional originalist" actually undermines his argument. For "Constitutionally originalist" SCOTUS majorities have delivered many decisions that establish that private companies enjoy many of the rights of individuals, including the right to express political opinions.

Now if the OP could show, to the satisfaction of a court, that he was materially harmed by StackExchange changing their logo, e.g that he was denied jobs or contracts because  he was seen as insufficiently originalist, he might have a cause of action. This seems unlikely; again,  the trend in the USA is for more and more corporations, even in traditionally conservative industries such as oil and defense, to adopt corporate policies supporting LGBT rights.

Absent that, at best , he might- or might not- be able to claim a technical violation of the CC-BY-SA license. In my layperson's opinion this claim is spurious, but I am open to rebuttal by an intellectual property lawyer. As to the OP, who is also not known to me to be a lawyer, we will have to agree to disagree.

I am failing to see as well why my suggestion of a disclaimer on the OPs profile fails to mitigate such concerns. Something along the lines of

> I consistently support (across the Internet and in real life) an
>   originalist view of Constitutional interpretation. Therefore, no
>   inference should be drawn that opinions expressed by StackExchange are
>   shared by me.

The OP seems on the verge of quitting SO over this issue, which, in my view, would be a shame, because he seems to have contributed a great deal of valuable technical content.

And by the way I did not downvote the OP, because I support this right to dissent. But I do not support his insistence on suppressing StackExchange's expression of a political  opinion with which he disagrees.

Comment: In your view, is Stack Exchange, Inc.'s expression suppressed by my proposed compromise? "the rainbow logo be immediately removed from user profile pages (all tabs), and that a disclaimer be added to the logo on other pages, in such a fashion that it appears in mouseover text and also when the page is printed, stating that the message represents the viewpoint of Stack Exchange, Inc., but may not reflect the views of individual users."

Comment: In no way have I suggested that Stack Exchange doesn't have the right to disseminate their opinion.  If you think I have, then please reread my post more slowly.  I'm against their use of my profile and my writing in connection with their opinion.

Comment: Also, this post was coming anyway, your comment prompted me to add one additional paragraph, and since I'm aware that many people judge meta posts on first impressions, I chose to put that paragraph at the top.

Comment: BTW, you may change "also not known to me to be a lawyer" to "also not a lawyer".  I freely admit that I am not a lawyer -- I have neither law degree nor license, only my understanding and a firm belief that it is immoral to write laws or contracts in a way that common people can't understand and discuss.

Comment: It is up to you and StackExchange to negotiate if you find their content objectionable. I hope that some mutually agreeable compromise can be reached so that your valuable contributions can be preserved.

Comment: There should be no `StackExchange's expression of a political opinion` _at all_, isn't it just that simple ? I'm annoyed that the rainbow and slogan were there, and I would be as annoyed by a "pro-traditional-marriage" logo / slogan. And I swear that until now I always honestly assumed that this was the default spirit on any website for programmers that does not explicitly state in its name or license any political orientation. Hard to believe of SE. I'll just put my own "no-politics-intended" disclaimer in my profile for the next time that SE places other political stuff there.