# Stack Overflow logo in rainbow colours

Tags: feature-request

In the past this has been possible.

For a day - please bring it back for those that have been killed by hatred in America.

Comment: For anyone who happened to miss it, pretty sure the OP is talking about [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow?cb=1) that happened a while back.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @EdHeal votes on meta *may* indicate agreement/disagreement, rather than post quality.

Comment: Quoting: "2015 saw a total of 11,774 terrorist attacks worldwide, resulting in 28,328 deaths and more than 35,000 injuries. In addition, more than 12,100 people were kidnapped or taken hostage."    The rainbow logo was used to commemorate the event that gave some hope to reduce this horrible carnage.  What happened in Florida gives little hope.

Comment: Being selective about what to celebrate probably goes over better than being selective about what to mourn. I wouldn't be offended if they did this but I'm not going to blame them if they decide not to either.

Answer (score 41):

I don't think this should happen for two reasons:

1) There was a lot of backlash the last time they changed to a rainbow logo, no matter how temporary it was. A large part of this seemed to be from people who saw it as completely unnecessary, given that the issue was in no way related to programming. For examples of backlash, see the question about [the policy of changing the logo](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297908/what-is-the-policy-for-stack-overflow-and-political-matters-such-as-the-logo-co?lq=1) and the comments posted there, along with the [discussion about the license](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298004/remember-when-you-promised-not-to-imply-that-i-support-your-political-message?lq=1) also brought up as a result of the change.

2) *More importantly,* there has not been a logo change for other, larger attacks in other countries recently. People will start arguing that other attacks should be honored this way, past and future.

Unfortunately, another attack is bound to happen somewhere in the world in the next 6 months. (If I'm wrong and it takes longer, I will be glad to be wrong.) If Stack Overflow honors this attack with a logo or other site change, it will set a precedent that may eventually have the logo or site changing weekly or monthly, probably even daily. (I pray it never comes to this.)

I'm all for honoring the victims. It's a tragedy what happened, and I will never argue against that. This answer is in no way intended to say otherwise. But it'll cause more strife than anything on Stack Overflow (and Meta Stack Overflow) if the logo is changed for so much as a day. We need to find other ways to honor these victims, ways that won't cause disagreements or grief.

One alternative is that interested users could choose to change their profile images in support of the victims. In this way, the individual users get to decide what their message is and how it's conveyed. The "About Me" section is also useful for this purpose. Individuals honoring the victims of select events will go over far better than the team deciding to force the message of honor on everyone.

Comment: "next 6 months" That's incredibly optimistic. At the rate we're going we might as well permanently rebrand Stack Overflow with rainbows and unicorns. (Not that I'd be opposed to doing *that* apart from what is happening in the world...)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is. If we can make it just two months without another attack somewhere, I'd be happy. The way things are today... That's not at all likely.

Comment: Another reason not to change it is that there's no thematic similarity between the event and Stack Overflow as a company or as a site within the Stack Exchange network (there wasn't one last time, either).

Comment: That's part of what caused the backlash last time, the fact it has nothing to do with programming. While that's a reason a lot of people would (and have) argue(d) the logo should not be changed, it's also a reason the company can _actively ignore_ as they have the rights to change the logo as they see fit. They cannot ignore, however, that they already have proof there will be, likely significant, backlash, and a similar situation has already shown that if they create the precedent, people will request similar changes for other situations.

Comment: @BoltClock Did you call a rainbow and unicorn? [see my profile picture]

Comment: +1 We don't want SO becoming like [Google Doodles](http://www.google.com/doodles)