# Would you like stackoverflowoverflow.com for free?

Tags: discussion, scope, low-quality-posts, new-users, split-stack-overflow

tl;dr: I own the domain name StackOverflowOverflow.com.  I cannot build something good for the community with it, and I want to gift it to someone who has an idea that will benefit the Stack Overflow community.

#### History

Yesterday, 9 years ago, [Tom Ritter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8435/tom-ritter) registered `stackoverflowoverflow.com` with the intention of creating a discussion site for topics and discussion styles that didn't fit the Stack Overflow paradigm.  Less than a year later [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) was created, replacing [UserVoice](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506230618/https://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general?status_id=10395), and [Tom gave stackoverflowoverflow.com to me](https://web.archive.org/web/20161221204353/http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41679/would-you-like-stackoverflowoverflow-com) to use it to allow discussion of slightly offtopic Stack Overflow questions.  Over time [I attempted this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46551/stackoverflowoverflow-to-be-or-not-to-be), first with [Stack Exchange 1.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299101/what-was-stack-exchange-1-0), then suggesting [a site via Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related), but the first was a failure as the system didn't support the needed migration/import functionality, and the second because the community that formed around the site wanted something substantially different (and they formed [a great, useful site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) - just not what was intended, taking [a hard turn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73382/please-stop-using-softwareengineering-se-as-your-toilet-bowl) during site beta).

#### I can't do it

Over the last six years I've watched as Stack Exchange Inc became a more socially and politically active company, and I've reduced my participation each time they attempted to deputize the community into becoming advocates for their specific social and political views, most which are shared by less than half the US, and little of the rest of the world. Recent decisions and policy reaffirm that they are intentionally pursuing an activist organization and community, and are now resolved on forcing the community into compliance with their voice on all network sites. This question isn't about this larger, intractable issue, but I wanted to provide context for my decision to leave and the dispossession of this domain.

**Since it looks like it's time to let go of this part of my life I expect someone else can do more with this domain than I would be able to.**

As [Tom Ritter did 8 years ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20161221204353/http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41679/would-you-like-stackoverflowoverflow-com):

#### Do you want it?

Would anyone like to pick up the cost of renewal and keep the domain? If not, it will probably go into domain limbo in 2019 and get auto-registered by a squatter.

On the off chance there're multiple people who would like it, post your idea, and I'll gift it to whichever one everyone likes best.

#### Intention

My intention is to find a use that would benefit Stack Overflow and its users. It's free.  I could go ahead and do a number of things with it, but none of those possibilities sits well with me.  It was gifted to me because it could be something useful for the community to use.  Maybe even a simple [Discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_%28software%29) server would be enough to provide something Stack Overflow cannot and never will.  I don't know - all I do know is that I'm not going to be able to do that for the community.

Perhaps someone else can, and giving it away for free to whomever has the idea the community most likes seems like a good way to ensure it's a benefit to the community - not a drag, and not a target.

This isn't a domain sale to the general public - I'm posting this question in the hopes that the community will come up with some interesting ideas worth trying, and someone will put forth the effort to test one or more possible uses.

**I want it to benefit the Stack Overflow community.**

<sub>Be aware: now that Stack Exchange Inc is a Real Company™ with Real Lawyers™ and Real Investors™ they may choose at any time to enforce their trademark.  At the time the domain was created it was a very friendly and community oriented company, willing to allow users a great deal of latitude, but they may no longer have the legal freedom to allow this sort of thing to continue. Caveat emptor.</sub>

Comment: [Stack Exchange already tried supporting those questions, they even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out. C'est la vie.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/102937)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes.  That's the site I proposed on Area51, and the sharp turn it took. I disagree that such a site could never be productive and useful, but this isn't the place to discuss that. There may be a completely different and more interesting use for the domain than this - I'm not suggesting that someone take up the torch of that concept.  Any concept is fine if it'll be used and useful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I hope the community finds this discussion question on topic and useful enough to be re-opened, but if it remains closed I'll accept that judgement.

Comment: @RobertColumbia The "sell" portion is a joke.  That's an absurd amount for any domain name, and I thought it would be obvious.  I've edited that part out to avoid a joke becoming the sticking point.

Comment: I think the bigger story is that we're losing a long time user, because they perceive that Stack Overflow has strayed from the goal of just being a programming question and answer site.

Comment: Well, I've already closed this once.  I'll leave it to the community managers to decide if they want to close it again, but I don't really see how taking a swipe at SE and publicizing an off-network site as an "alternative" is in any way on-topic here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The blog post was pretty clear that they want feedback from the community. Wouldn't a long time user deciding to leave due to recent events be just that sort of feedback? I get that it's off-topic, but it's exactly the sort of wake-up message that SE needs to be hearing, instead of trying to hide it away and pretend like non-users matter and experienced users don't.

Comment: @mason: The blog post also, above all else, talks about *how* we should communicate things.  This post is not a stellar example.  It's mostly a ragequit.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're continuing to miss the point: users believe that Stack Overflow is losing its core mission. They're here to do programming questions and answers. That's it. They feel like SE is deviating from that, and they're leaving and they want SE to know why. You can call it a rage quit if you want, the end result is the same: a person that has contributed quite a bit over the years is leaving.

Comment: @mason: And you're continuing to miss the point as well.  This post is ironically illustrative of what happens when a community member skirts along the edges of policy.  If people don't want to "fit in" and decide to leave by their own personal choice, it's their right and privilege to do so.

Comment: At least give Adam a chance to find a new home for this domain before he stops paying for it. (Or he could use the contact form instead, if that makes everyone feel better...)

Comment: @RobertHarvey A long time user announcing that they're leaving, and giving their feedback as to why they're doing so, shouldn't qualify as skirting along the edge of policy. I "see" the irony you think I'm missing, I just don't agree that it's ironic.

Comment: @mason: Sure.  Just make sure you're providing a reasonably accurate characterization.  Here's mine: "I disagree with how SE runs things, and I am leaving.  By the way, wanna buy my domain name I created as an alternate forum for disenfranchised users?"  C'mon.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sure, that's a fair enough description. I just think that we should be smart enough people to recognize the actual value in the post. Honestly, I don't care that he's selling a domain, and probably most others don't either. But several experienced users lately have been expressing their dissatisfaction with SE recently, and some have discussed leaving. Well, here's an example of it. Does SE keep track of active users that leave? Conduct an exit interview/survey? Because in my opinion, we should be far more worried about losing experienced users than a few dissatisfied non-users.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I hope my edit addresses some of your concerns about my intentions for this post.

Comment: Would anyone like to buy my super-great domain, stackstackoverflowoverflowoverflow.com.com?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's a fair characterisation in every way except for the fact that he's not selling that domain, he's offering to gift it to someone who is prepared to pay the renewal fee. (As he clarified in his edit.)

Comment: Dismiss as ragequit, but this and others seem more like [sadquits](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Sadquit) to me.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt: He already clarified that.

Comment: Can someone explain what @AdamDavis is referring to with his comments about SE becoming politicised?

Comment: @ChuckLeButt: there is a political view that treating people decently is in itself political. I don't speak for Adam, and he may wish to clarify for himself, but some American right-wingers think that helping disadvantaged/marginalised groups is politically liberal or left-leaning. Personally I think that some of the responses we have seen recently (including leaving) are a gross over-reaction, and probably a serious misunderstanding of the blog pot that started all this. But, hey-ho, we are where we are.

Comment: You can do like I do with stackoverfiow.com; a good troll to misdirect people. see this relevant [meta post](http://meta.stackoverfiow.com/questions/2827654/how-to-rick-roll-unsuspecting-users).

Comment: @ChuckLeButt I’ve intentionally avoided going deeper into that discussion, but I will say that halfer’s assumption that this is all about the latest blog post is wrong. This is a path they’ve been traveling down for years, the domain came up for renewal yesterday, and now seems as good a time as any to make a clean break and tie up loose ends.

Comment: @halfer when you say 'decently' you mean like not mis-characterising their views?

Comment: Hi @Oranges. Yes, definitely. I don't seek to mis-characterise anyone's views, for what its worth, though (and I mean everyone here) I'd note that people exhibit political behaviour that they didn't explicitly take a view on, and much political opinion can be a psychological counter-reaction to the wider social context in which people experience the society around around. I don't use "right-wingers" as a perjorative, by the way - there is some evidence that our politics choose us, and not the other way around.

Comment: I think post talks something legit and meaningful because many important questions on SO is not easily seen on the page, the contextual linking of question is as if it is influenced by some bot or some community by boosting it.We need to think about this degree of freedom of question it is rotating and evolving.

Comment: @halfer I think the point you're missing is that this is not to do with fluffy issues like the most recent blog post, but about explicitly political interventions by Stack Overflow management like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand), [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow?cb=1), and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114005/how-does-sopa-threaten-stack-overflow-stack-exchange), all of which were controversial.

Comment: @IMSoP: I hear you. I set out my views on that theme [some years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298252/472495), and broadly I said that the issues that SO takes a stand on are relevant either as a leading technology firm (SOPA) and a model employer (anti-discrimination). I am somewhat minded to regard all of these things as not very controversial, in the sense that the volume of the counter-reaction is surprising, but the ongoing US-centric culture war has created an unusual socio-political and media context.

Comment: @halfer I happen to agree with your personal politics, but not with your assumption that those politics are uncontroversial, or that the controversy is anything other than the natural pattern of politics throughout history. That's the last I'll say on it here.

Comment: @AdamDavis Surely the point of this post was to register your disapproval with the way things are going. If you don't explicitly state your views, what was the point...? I have literally no idea what you're talking about or why you're leaving.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt The point of this post, according to its title and 90% of its content, was to find a new owner for stackoverflowoverflow.com

Comment: Please don't leave. I share your distaste for the political (/"not political, just about treating people decently") stances the company has taken, but Stack Overflow remains a valuable resource to new and experienced programmers alike, and none of the leftist activism that the company has engaged in has *yet* damaged that. If right-leaning members leave, we'll gradually lose ground to the April Wensels of the world, our ability to criticise others' posts (and thereby readers' ability to find content that is useful and correct) will slip away, and the entire industry will be left poorer.

Comment: *"I wanted to provide context for my decision to leave and the dispossession of this domain"* - this is at best naive, and at worst disingenuous. It doesn't have any bearing of any prospective uses of the domain in question whatsoever. If you want to neutralise speculation that the main purpose of the question is to rage quit, you should edit to remove the bit where you announce and explain your departure. An example of *useful* context would be adding a link to a page where you announce and discuss your departure in an appropriate forum to do so.

Comment: Isn't it obvious? It should load Stack Overflow recursively until it overflows. Or it should overflow throwing stack overflow errors.

Comment: @MarkAmery your comment reminds me of something that I've been wondering for a while. Could we all *please* stop considering treating humans with dignity as "leftist activism"? It should be clear that **respecting human dignity is apolitical** and it's not like the "right wing people" are some kind of monsters with no regard to other people. If someone disregards the dignity and rights of fellow humans, the problem is not that they disagree with "leftists", *they* are the problem.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I (and everyone else who is to the right of *Stack Exchange, Inc.* on social justice issues, which is evidently most of the community) do not consider what is being asked of us by Stack Exchange to amount to "treating humans with dignity". If we did, we wouldn't be objecting to it. "Treating humans with dignity" does not require relaxing our moderation standards, nor accepting a narrative about women or non-whites in which they are generally unable to cope with criticism that white men would easily tolerate. We don't think the former is a good idea, nor the latter true.

Comment: I agree with @Will. Besides, it's a terrible domain name.

Comment: @MarkAmery you **can** keep the moderation standards without sacrificing politeness. some attitudes seen on SO are quite harsh thus yes, even "white men" (of which I happen to be one) would find them inappropriate. As an example of website that keeps moderation standards high while preserving kindness and openness see for instance Ask Ubuntu. Having said that, SE is being accused (see also above) to be "leftist" because it shows respect for the human dignity of gay people or legal immigrants. How does any of this equate to being a "leftist"?

Comment: I second @Mark's plea for you to stay, Adam. For what's it worth, Meta must be seen by outsiders and users of the main site as a daft playground for us diehards, but broadly most users of the main site - who do not even sign in - are not left or right or up or down on this issue. It's good that there are folks who care about quality, you included. I am a strong quality advocate as well, while also wanting to be welcoming of more people, which need not be a zero-sum game.

Comment: @ChuckLeButt See this blog post https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ and then look for a number of really heavily voted meta posts from afterward.  Even though Adam said his dissatisfaction started earlier; that post and the discussions it's kicked off appear to've brought the issue to a head now.

Comment: @MarkAmery "which is evidently most of the community" [citation needed]

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto because in the highly polarized state of us politics the left has embraced those causes meaning that a large part of the us right feels compelled to reflexively oppose them.

Comment: ...and this entire chain of comments is a significant indicator of why people either leave or dramatically scale back efforts towards stack...

Comment: I think the last, small-text remark about the trademark is the most relevant: it's probably only Stack Exchange Inc. who could actually *use* this domain, especially going forward; they could "agree to let the community do its thing", but I don't see them leaving it up for grabs, especially if the site became drastically at odds with the main site (and if it doesn't, might as well just use the SE domain). In that sense, this is no different from a general proposal to do "something else" on another domain. ...and when you put it like that I think this  might actually be "too broad".

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch I think it's because neither side actually understands the other. I think the miscommunication's summed up well by [Joel's quote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297871/5212501): **"On Stack Overflow we don't care if you're black, white, brown, or purple, as long as you know the answer to a programming question, you'll get the upvote. We don't care if you're straight, gay, bi, trans, queer, asexual, intersexual, questioning, poly, or a sandwich, we only care if you're right.  Whoever you are, you are equal in our eyes "**  ...

Comment: ... One side hears that and thinks "Well yeah, we don't care. *Of course we should treat everyone equally*." The other side thinks "Well yeah, we don't care, *so the question of intolerance should never come up.* Race, gender, and sexual orientation shouldn't be discussed here anyway. We don't care." But from the opposite perspectives that's viewed as "race, gender, and sexual orientation are relevant on SO now", or "we shouldn't have to be tolerant to other races, genders, and sexual orientations". It's a bummer; they're not actually mutually exclusive views.

Comment: @LordFarquaad While there might be people whose view is that it's improper for discussion of intolerance (or discrimination, or diversity, or whatever) to happen on Meta at all, I don't think that's a view held by most of the people hostile to the blog post. I don't recall seeing it voiced since the blog post went up, at least - though I wasn't really paying attention for it, so perhaps it went under my nose. We (or, I think it's 'we' - but at least, I personally) object to the company's stance on gender and racial issues, not to the fact that they're being discussed at all.

Comment: @MarkAmery I'm not sure I follow. What's the company's stance on gender and racial issues, and what issue do you think most users take with it?

Comment: Voting to close as "no longer reproducible", because the domain name appears to have expired and is unreachable.

Comment: @LordFarquaad the side that thinks "Well yeah, we don't care, *so the question of intolerance should never come up*. Race, gender, and sexual orientation shouldn't be discussed here anyway. We don't care." **also thinks** "Well yeah, we don't care. *Of course we should treat everyone equally.*". They just **disagree that** treating everyone equally entails that the question actually comes up - and, in fact, consider that bringing the question up would **actively interfere with** treating everyone equally. (I say this having seen countless examples of such interference over the last ~12 years.)

Comment: (But perhaps my point is better made by Factor Mystic's comment on Joel's answer there.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it would be fun for that domain to be a 2d physics-based visualization of the stack overflow questions that are being posted. When a user hits the site the screen will populate with the most recent however many questions (maybe five or ten), and each question will be represented with a block, and as new questions are posted, they are dropped onto the pile until the whole screen just fills up with questions.

Comment: What’s going on now? The site fails to load, on my phone at least.

Answer (score -18):

If no one else steps up, I can have this domain redirect to [stackoverflow.proboards.com](http://stackoverflow.proboards.com/) (or similar) and set up a forum there.

I'm still not sure what kinds of discussion would go on there, but I could envision a new topics board where people could propose uses for it, and then those might graduate to actual boards on the forum.

Thoughts?

+1 or -1 for the new topics idea?

Antother thing I'm wondering is how this will differ from the idea of a third place that SO chat already covers.

Comment: Looks like the community has spoken, let's not do the free-for-all on topics.