# Show the number of upvotes again after hitting the rep cap

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, reputation-history

With the old profile, we could see all upvotes individually on the reputation tab by clicking on the expand arrow. This allowed us to see upvotes even if they didn’t give you any more reputation because you hit the daily reputation cap.

Now, with the new profile page, the expanding is no longer there, and there does not seem to be a way to see how many upvotes you got on a certain day for a post:

[image: Upvotes on reputation tab]

Could you readd the old feature or make the number of total upvotes per day  available elsewhere (e.g. in parentheses at the end)?

---

Okay… I just realized where that information went: If you hover over the “upvote” text, it tells you how often the post was upvoted. For example: “this answer was upvoted 10 times”. This works but seems really hidden; could we just make the number more visible instead? For example like this:

[image: Proposed way to show the number of upvotes in parentheses]

Comment: Ugh, first world rep farmer problems.

Comment: You could also look at the question timeline.

Comment: Doesn't it already show you 'number of events' if an answer is upvoted more than once?

Comment: @Unihedron You gotta include the [youtube video if you're going to say that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwvlbJ0h35A)

Comment: Wow, ever since they showed the picture of the 100k mug, all the 70kers have changed…

Comment: @abarnert That has nothing to do. I don’t care much about rep; I do care about my posts though ([a lot actually](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258057/send-notification-when-question-is-closed-or-deleted)), so I want to keep track of what happens to them.

Comment: I'm confused.  I'm looking at my reputation tab, sub-tab post, and I see an arrow `|>` that lets me expand and see all my upvotes even when I break 200.  I guess you are looking at the time subtab?

Comment: @Yakk Oh what… I didn’t realize I was on a different subtab! Was that thing always there? Thanks, that’s exactly what I was missing :)

Comment: time is nearly useless, I agree.