# What happens from the asker's perspective when their question gets deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Just came across this really bad [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386841/how-do-i-fix-in-java-programming) in time to also downvote and give my delete vote; which got the question deleted.

I assume: when the user is "around" while the question is up; he can observe all the downvotes and comments he receives.

But assume he isn't; but coming back an hour later ... is anything of that still visible to him? Or does he just come back and finds his question "vanished"? Without any further information what exactly happened?

Comment: I guess it's still visible for them in the "deleted recent posts". But a new user is unlikely to know about that option.

Comment: If the post garners a lot of downvotes and  then gets deleted, there is a high chance that the user will get q-banned. In that case the banner clearly mentions, "edit your previous posts", so I think the user will then check his recently deleted posts. (not so sure)

Comment: @BhargavRao I thought a post ban required _several_ bad posts? (Barring moderator intervention for spam etc, of course).

Comment: I have a post asked and deleted about a year ago [at Math.SE meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/21680/279150 "10K Math.SE link - 'Hint: Programmers.SE doesn't do coding help and expect research before asking'") where I am well under 10k. No trace of it in my profile, not in the "recent deleted" lists, but when I get directly to the link I can see the question, comments and answers. It's overall like a 10K view of deleted post except that if there were separately deleted answers I wouldn't see these... Oh wait I can see link to it in badges section of my profile, just found it

Comment: @S.L.Barth, The q-ban algo is weird, I've seen one user (an year back), who had complained on meta that they were q-banned. They had only one post which was just downvoted. Only SE can tell if the q-ban algo bans users over one post.

Comment: @BhargavRao the only way I can think of this to happen is that user's account was ["restarted after deletion"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234518/165773), so that their old incarnation posts are disassociated and system only keeps some mark that account belongs to previously blocked user

Comment: @gnat Thanks! That clears a lot of questions about the 1 post q-banned users.

Comment: @BhargavRao wonder if that "restarted account" mark is visible to moderators or only for users with dev access, would you mind checking? If mods can't see it, maybe we can discuss if SE team could make it visible at diamond level access as well

Comment: @gnat Nopes, it is not visible to mods. If a user is deleted by mods and recreates his account, then it is visible to us. (Implemented after Brad's request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277230/automatically-suspend-accounts-recreated-after-a-moderator-deleted-the-original)).

Comment: I see, thanks @BhargavRao. If that is a significant annoyance for moderators then we can ask SE team to enable diamond visibility for this mark

Comment: @BhargavRao maybe the q-ban normally trips only after multiple bad questions, but can ban after a single question if that question is a terrible, horrible, abysmally bad cesspool of a question.

Comment: @RobertColumbia this is unlikely so, [official statement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236568/165773) on this sounds quite clear: "The first question doesn't count, because we're programmers and enjoy testing gravity with our faces and some pavement from time to time..." Poor first question can trigger some rate limit ([immediately](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/322265/839601)) but not ban

Comment: Actually, those questions are already going to get deleted automatically by the roomba, so using a delete vote isn't really needed.

Comment: Is there a reason to **not** notify the user when one of its questions is deleted?

Comment: @Veve That was my thought as well. I wonder how many newbies would ever find their way to those deleted questions. On the other hand, I wonder how many of those that put up such questions would actually care.

Comment: @Veve: There's been [a feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258057/send-notification-when-question-is-closed-or-deleted) for that but it was declined. The thread has some reasoning, whether you agree with it or not. Edit: also a [site-wide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93842/send-authors-an-inbox-message-if-their-question-gets-closed) request.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The user won't get notified their question was deleted, but they are still able to access the deleted question from https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/theirID, which is available, although not entirely visible from their profile*

Going to their question, they will see it's deleted, the reason it was deleted, comments on the post. They are able to edit their question and [cast an undelete vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43942/can-the-owner-of-a-question-get-it-undeleted-with-his-vote-alone-and-also-could/105300#105300) (Thanks [@Tiny Giant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344327/what-happens-from-an-questioner-perspective-when-their-question-gets-deleted-on/344375?noredirect=1#comment450687_344375)). This won't undelete their post, as they'll need 2 other users to vote to undelete (self-deleted posts can be instantly undeleted by a user though).

From [deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions):

> What happens when a post is deleted?
>
> Once a post has been deleted, it will disappear for all users except developers, moderators, and users with over 10,000 reputation. Deleted questions will also always be visible to their authors, regardless of the author's reputation. However, deleted posts can be undeleted by casting undelete votes. Once a post has 3 undelete votes, it will no longer be deleted.
> Self-deleted posts can be viewed, edited, and undeleted by their original authors.

What a deleted post will look like to the author:

[image: deleted question]

* I recently had a question deleted and it took me a while to realise the question was in fact deleted. I wasn't notified, and it took a while to realise where I could even access it from.

Comment: Re: _"They are able to edit their question and cast an undelete vote"_: [_"If a post was deleted by users other than its owner, the owner's undelete vote will no longer instantly undelete - it will be counted just like other users' votes to undelete. Note that if a moderator participated in the deletion, only another moderator can undelete."_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105300/288751)

Comment: Sorry, that's what I was getting at: they can _cast_ a vote to undelete, but it won't actually undelete (unless it's self-deleted). I'll edit

Comment: I posted that not to negate your point, but to support it. That way you can link directly to the reference and quote the relevant information, which removes the need for _"(I think)"_.

Comment: Haha yes thank you, I just realised when I edited that I had doubts when I was writing that because I wasn't sure. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Also keep in mind that [answers deleted through review can be unilaterally undeleted by the poster (except if one of the reviewers was a diamond moderator), but it raises an auto-flag for moderator review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/288751)

Comment: Can one view the answers attached to the deleted post? What about answers which were deleted separately from the question?