# Does a user get notified of question deletion

Tags: support, deleted-questions, notifications

Assuming we have a user on the platform who posts a bad question which gets closed and deleted within 15 minutes. The user comes back 20 minutes later. What does he see / get?

- Does he still see the question?
- Did he get a notification?
- Can he still read the close reason + comments + potential answers?

Comment: On Meta SE: [When a user has one of his question or answer deleted, why don't you notify him about the deletion, and send the removed content by email?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209694/when-a-user-has-one-of-his-question-or-answer-deleted-why-dont-you-notify-him)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344327/what-happens-from-the-askers-perspective-when-their-question-gets-deleted/344375

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Users can see their recently deleted questions by visiting their profile, go to the "Questions" tab, and clicking on the "deleted recent questions" link.

They can see non-deleted comments under their question, but not sure what happens with answers. Users who own answers on deleted questions can see the deleted question and their deleted answer, but I believe not other answers on that question.

Users do not get a notification when their questions are deleted, and [there are no plans to implement that feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258057/send-notification-when-question-is-closed-or-deleted). They *may* get a [notification if the deletion caused a rep change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209694/when-a-user-has-one-of-his-question-or-answer-deleted-why-dont-you-notify-him), but the rep change notification wont include a link to the now deleted question.

Comment: Afaik only rep gains generate notifications. So only deletions which lead to rep gains (downvoted posts) or deletions followed by a rep gain caused by something else will notify the user something's happened.