# Did one of my questions (maybe older than the deleted recently page's period) get deleted recently and is therefore not shown on that page?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, deleted-comments

In an [answer on meta.se on Oct 28 '19 at 18:49](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336951/273829) I mentioned having asked **41** questions in my entire SO lifetime.

Right now I saw that [there are only **40**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744774?tab=questions). The [*deleted recently* page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/1744774) is empty. (OTH, I can see a deleted *answer* on meta.se from Oct 10 '19.)

I'm pretty sure I didn't read/write the number wrong then.

Has one of my questions on SO been deleted or did I really read/write the number wrongly in the past?

Supplementary questions:

- Why is there no kind of pro-active automated message in the Inbox that something (Q, A or comment) has been deleted so that it's not recognized just by chance (or maybe never)?
- How long is *recent* in terms of the *deleted recently* page?
- How can I see which and why–to be able to learn and improve–it has been deleted after the expired *recent* period?
- And, well, to the *why*: I cant' even see at the deleted meta.se answer I mentioned above why. There's just a link to the generic [help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers) and that's it. How can this be improved?

Comment: relevant [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). Note that the link doesn't say *Deleted recently*, it says *deleted recent questions*. The difference is that it only shows questions that you have asked over the last 60 days but are now deleted. Questions that you asked in 2010 will not show up on your profile if they are deleted *recently* (in the lst 60 days).

Comment: first bullet is a dupe of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258057/send-notification-when-question-is-closed-or-deleted

Comment: You need a mod to find your recently deleted question. They can run a search with `deleted:1`, something you can do once you reach 10K but only for your own posts.

Comment: This is your most recently deleted question https://stackoverflow.com/q/53042572

Comment: @SamuelLiew Thx for the info. [That, BTW, is exactly one of the reasons/use cases](https://github.com/mojohaus/wagon-maven-plugin/issues/35) why I–still and despite the answer there–second [Send notification when question is closed or deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258057/1744774).